# Using NumPy to build an array of all combinations of two arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, cartesian-product

I'm trying to run over the parameters space of a six-parameter function to study its numerical behavior before trying to do anything complex with it, so I'm searching for an efficient way to do this.

My function takes float values given in a 6-dim NumPy array as input. What I tried to do initially was this:

First, I created a function that takes two arrays and generate an array with all combinations of values from the two arrays:

```
from numpy import *

def comb(a, b):
    c = []
    for i in a:
        for j in b:
            c.append(r_[i,j])
    return c
```

Then, I used `reduce()` to apply that to m copies of the same array:

```
def combs(a, m):
    return reduce(comb, [a]*m)
```

Finally, I evaluate my function like this:

```
values = combs(np.arange(0, 1, 0.1), 6)
for val in values:
    print F(val)
```

This works, but it's *way* too slow. I know the space of parameters is huge, but this shouldn't be so slow. I have only sampled 10<sup>6</sup> (a million) points in this example and it took more than 15 seconds just to create the array `values`.

Is there a more efficient way of doing this with NumPy?

I can modify the way the function `F` takes its arguments if it's necessary.

Comment: For the fastest cartesian product I've found, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11146645/577088). (Since the question is phrased quite differently from this one, I deem that the questions are not duplicates, but the best solution to the two questions is the same.)

Answer (score 211, accepted):

In newer versions of NumPy (>1.8.x), [`numpy.meshgrid()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) provides a much faster implementation:

For [pv's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208118/using-numpy-to-build-an-array-of-all-combinations-of-two-arrays/1235363#1235363):

```
In [113]:

%timeit cartesian(([1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7]))
10000 loops, best of 3: 135 µs per loop
In [114]:

cartesian(([1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7]))

Out[114]:
array([[1, 4, 6],
       [1, 4, 7],
       [1, 5, 6],
       [1, 5, 7],
       [2, 4, 6],
       [2, 4, 7],
       [2, 5, 6],
       [2, 5, 7],
       [3, 4, 6],
       [3, 4, 7],
       [3, 5, 6],
       [3, 5, 7]])
```

[`numpy.meshgrid()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) used to be two-dimensional only, but now it is capable of being multidimensional. In this case, three-dimensional:

```
In [115]:

%timeit np.array(np.meshgrid([1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7])).T.reshape(-1,3)
10000 loops, best of 3: 74.1 µs per loop
In [116]:

np.array(np.meshgrid([1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7])).T.reshape(-1,3)

Out[116]:
array([[1, 4, 6],
       [1, 5, 6],
       [2, 4, 6],
       [2, 5, 6],
       [3, 4, 6],
       [3, 5, 6],
       [1, 4, 7],
       [1, 5, 7],
       [2, 4, 7],
       [2, 5, 7],
       [3, 4, 7],
       [3, 5, 7]])
```

Note that the order of the final result is slightly different.

Comment: `np.stack(np.meshgrid([1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7]), -1).reshape(-1, 3)` will give the right order

Comment: @CT Zhu Is there an easy way to transform this so that the a matrix holding the different arrays as columns is used as input instead?

Comment: It should be noted that meshgrid only works for smaller range sets, I have a large one and I get error: ValueError: maximum supported dimension for an ndarray is 32, found 69

Comment: @mikkom, nothing will handle sets greater than 32.  Even if each was of size 2, the number of combinations would be 2**32, 4 Gb.

Comment: @Eric this solution no longer gives the correct order

Answer (score 188):

Here's a pure-NumPy implementation. It's about 5 times faster than using [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html).

### Python 3:

```
import numpy as np

def cartesian(arrays, out=None):
    """
    Generate a Cartesian product of input arrays.

    Parameters
    ----------
    arrays : list of array-like
        1-D arrays to form the Cartesian product of.
    out : ndarray
        Array to place the Cartesian product in.

    Returns
    -------
    out : ndarray
        2-D array of shape (M, len(arrays)) containing Cartesian products
        formed of input arrays.

    Examples
    --------
    >>> cartesian(([1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7]))
    array([[1, 4, 6],
           [1, 4, 7],
           [1, 5, 6],
           [1, 5, 7],
           [2, 4, 6],
           [2, 4, 7],
           [2, 5, 6],
           [2, 5, 7],
           [3, 4, 6],
           [3, 4, 7],
           [3, 5, 6],
           [3, 5, 7]])

    """

    arrays = [np.asarray(x) for x in arrays]
    dtype = arrays[0].dtype

    n = np.prod([x.size for x in arrays])
    if out is None:
        out = np.zeros([n, len(arrays)], dtype=dtype)

    #m = n / arrays[0].size
    m = int(n / arrays[0].size)
    out[:,0] = np.repeat(arrays[0], m)
    if arrays[1:]:
        cartesian(arrays[1:], out=out[0:m, 1:])
        for j in range(1, arrays[0].size):
        #for j in xrange(1, arrays[0].size):
            out[j*m:(j+1)*m, 1:] = out[0:m, 1:]
    return out
```

### Python 2:

```
import numpy as np

def cartesian(arrays, out=None):
    arrays = [np.asarray(x) for x in arrays]
    dtype = arrays[0].dtype

    n = np.prod([x.size for x in arrays])
    if out is None:
        out = np.zeros([n, len(arrays)], dtype=dtype)

    m = n / arrays[0].size
    out[:,0] = np.repeat(arrays[0], m)
    if arrays[1:]:
        cartesian(arrays[1:], out=out[0:m, 1:])
        for j in xrange(1, arrays[0].size):
            out[j*m:(j+1)*m, 1:] = out[0:m, 1:]
    return out
```

Comment: Nice Pauli, this solves my 2D interpolation problem. Defining the data point coords for griddata was giving some trouble. Does this function make into the master numpy code?

Comment: why not creat `out` with `np.ndarray`, that saves time.

Comment: ever consider submitting this to be included in numpy?  this is not the first time I've gone looking for this functionality and found your post.

Comment: There is bug in this implementation. For arrays of strings for example: arrays[0].dtype = "|S3" and arrays[1].dtype = "|S5". So there is a need in finding the longest string in input and use its type in out = np.zeros([n, len(arrays)], dtype=dtype)

Comment: FYI:  seems to have made it into the scikit-learn package at `from sklearn.utils.extmath import cartesian`

Comment: I get memory error when I try to run: `a = arange(3333, dtype=int16)
cartesian(split(a, 3))`. This should use about 1111**3 * 16 bits of memory, ~2.6GB. Maybe I don't actually have enough free memory.. But is there much memory overhead for this method?

Comment: Not only is this faster, but it uses a third of the memory (at least in the case of how I was using itertools.combinations)

Comment: I just realized: this is slightly different from itertools.combinations, as this function respects the ordering of values whereas combinations doesn't, so this function returns more values than combinations does. Still very impressive, but unfortunately not what I was looking for :(

Comment: For posterity, the performant alternative to just using itertools.combinations can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16003217/n-d-version-of-itertools-combinations-in-numpy

Comment: What if the results donnot fit in memory ?  shouldn't this have the option to return a generator as well ?

Comment: For the fastest cartesian product I've found, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11146645/577088).

Comment: `TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method` thrown by `cartesian(arrays[1:], out=out[0:m,1:])`

Comment: @Boern or anyone else running into a `TypeError`, the function was written for python 2, and you are likely trying to run it with python 3. you can change two lines: `m = n / arrays[0].size` --> `m = int(n / arrays[0].size)` and `for j in xrange(1, arrays[0].size):` --> `for j in range(1, arrays[0].size):`

Comment: @Boern or you can use the function `cartesian_product_recursive` (or any of the other solutions) from @senderle's answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144513/numpy-cartesian-product-of-x-and-y-array-points-into-single-array-of-2d-points/11146645#11146645 IMO this is a better solution than having to potentially install and import a large library like `sklearn`

Comment: @barlaensdoonn Thanks to your comment the answer was edited.

Comment: Won't `np.empty` be much faster in case `if out is None:`?

Answer (score 43):

[itertools.combinations](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) is in general the fastest way to get combinations from a Python container (if you do in fact want combinations, i.e., arrangements *without* repetitions and independent of order; that's not what your code appears to be doing, but I can't tell whether that's because your code is buggy or because you're using the wrong terminology).

If you want something different than combinations perhaps other iterators in itertools, `product` or `permutations`, might serve you better. For example, it looks like your code is roughly the same as:

```
for val in itertools.product(np.arange(0, 1, 0.1), repeat=6):
    print F(val)
```

All of these iterators yield tuples, not lists or NumPy arrays, so if your *F* is picky about getting specifically a NumPy array, you'll have to accept the extra overhead of constructing or clearing and refilling one at each step.

Answer (score 18):

You can use `np.array(itertools.product(a, b))`.

Comment: np.array(list(itertools.product(l, l2)))

Comment: An explanation would be in order. Isn't it already covered in previous answers? What is different? What is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49870877/edit), not here in comments (****** ***without*** ****** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 12):

You can do something like this

```
import numpy as np

def cartesian_coord(*arrays):
    grid = np.meshgrid(*arrays)
    coord_list = [entry.ravel() for entry in grid]
    points = np.vstack(coord_list).T
    return points

a = np.arange(4)  # Fake data
print(cartesian_coord(*6*[a])
```

which gives

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2],
   ...,
   [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1],
   [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2],
   [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]])
```

Comment: Is there a way to get NumPy to accept more than 32 arrays for meshgrid? This method works for me as long as I don't pass more than 32 arrays.

Answer (score 11):

The following NumPy implementation should be approximately two times the speed of the given previous answers:

```
def cartesian2(arrays):
    arrays = [np.asarray(a) for a in arrays]
    shape = (len(x) for x in arrays)

    ix = np.indices(shape, dtype=int)
    ix = ix.reshape(len(arrays), -1).T

    for n, arr in enumerate(arrays):
        ix[:, n] = arrays[n][ix[:, n]]

    return ix
```

Comment: Looks good. By my rudimentary tests, this looks faster than the original answer for all pairs, triples, and 4-tuples of {1,2,...,100}. After that, the original answer wins.

Also, for future readers looking to generate all k-tuples of {1,...,n}, `np.indices((n,...,n)).reshape(k,-1).T` will do.

Comment: This only works for integers, while the accepted answer also works for floats.

Answer (score 10):

It looks like you want a grid to evaluate your function,  in which case you can use [numpy.ogrid](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ogrid.html) (open) or [numpy.mgrid](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.mgrid.html) (fleshed out):

```
import numpy

my_grid = numpy.mgrid[[slice(0, 1, 0.1)]*6]
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's yet another way, using pure NumPy, no recursion, no list comprehension, and no explicit for loops. It's about 20% slower than the original answer, and it's based on [np.meshgrid](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html).

```
def cartesian(*arrays):
    mesh = np.meshgrid(*arrays)  # Standard NumPy meshgrid
    dim = len(mesh)  # Number of dimensions
    elements = mesh[0].size  # Number of elements, any index will do
    flat = np.concatenate(mesh).ravel()  # Flatten the whole meshgrid
    reshape = np.reshape(flat, (dim, elements)).T  # Reshape and transpose
    return reshape
```

For example,

```
x = np.arange(3)
a = cartesian(x, x, x, x, x)
print(a)
```

gives

```
[[0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 2]
 ...,
 [2 2 2 2 0]
 [2 2 2 2 1]
 [2 2 2 2 2]]
```

Answer (score 7):

For a pure NumPy implementation of the [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of one-dimensional arrays (or flat Python lists), just use [meshgrid()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html), roll the axes with [transpose()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html), and reshape to the desired output:

```
 def cartprod(*arrays):
     N = len(arrays)
     return transpose(meshgrid(*arrays, indexing='ij'),
                      roll(arange(N + 1), -1)).reshape(-1, N)
```

Note this has the convention of the last axis changing the fastest ("C style" or "row-major").

```
In [88]: cartprod([1,2,3], [4,8], [100, 200, 300, 400], [-5, -4])
Out[88]:
array([[  1,   4, 100,  -5],
       [  1,   4, 100,  -4],
       [  1,   4, 200,  -5],
       [  1,   4, 200,  -4],
       [  1,   4, 300,  -5],
       [  1,   4, 300,  -4],
       [  1,   4, 400,  -5],
       [  1,   4, 400,  -4],
       [  1,   8, 100,  -5],
       [  1,   8, 100,  -4],
       [  1,   8, 200,  -5],
       [  1,   8, 200,  -4],
       [  1,   8, 300,  -5],
       [  1,   8, 300,  -4],
       [  1,   8, 400,  -5],
       [  1,   8, 400,  -4],
       [  2,   4, 100,  -5],
       [  2,   4, 100,  -4],
       [  2,   4, 200,  -5],
       [  2,   4, 200,  -4],
       [  2,   4, 300,  -5],
       [  2,   4, 300,  -4],
       [  2,   4, 400,  -5],
       [  2,   4, 400,  -4],
       [  2,   8, 100,  -5],
       [  2,   8, 100,  -4],
       [  2,   8, 200,  -5],
       [  2,   8, 200,  -4],
       [  2,   8, 300,  -5],
       [  2,   8, 300,  -4],
       [  2,   8, 400,  -5],
       [  2,   8, 400,  -4],
       [  3,   4, 100,  -5],
       [  3,   4, 100,  -4],
       [  3,   4, 200,  -5],
       [  3,   4, 200,  -4],
       [  3,   4, 300,  -5],
       [  3,   4, 300,  -4],
       [  3,   4, 400,  -5],
       [  3,   4, 400,  -4],
       [  3,   8, 100,  -5],
       [  3,   8, 100,  -4],
       [  3,   8, 200,  -5],
       [  3,   8, 200,  -4],
       [  3,   8, 300,  -5],
       [  3,   8, 300,  -4],
       [  3,   8, 400,  -5],
       [  3,   8, 400,  -4]])
```

If you want to change the *first* axis fastest ("[Fortran](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortran) style" or "column-major"), just change the `order` parameter of `reshape()` like this: `reshape((-1, N), order='F')`

Answer (score 2):

Pandas' [merge()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) offers a naive, fast solution to the problem:

```
# Given the lists
x, y, z = [1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7]

# Get dataframes with the same, constant index 
x = pd.DataFrame({'x': x}, index=np.repeat(0, len(x)))
y = pd.DataFrame({'y': y}, index=np.repeat(0, len(y)))
z = pd.DataFrame({'z': z}, index=np.repeat(0, len(z)))

# Get all permutations stored in a new dataframe
df = pd.merge(x, pd.merge(y, z, left_index=True, right_index=True),
              left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Comment: Yes, but the question is tagged with [NumPy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy).

Comment: And the title contains "NumPy".