# Fast math operations on an array in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a fairly simple math operation I'd like to perform on a array. Let me write out the example:

```
A = numpy.ndarray((255, 255, 3), dtype=numpy.single)
# ..
for i in range(A.shape[0]):
    for j in range(A.shape[1]):
        x = simple_func1(i)
        y = simple_func2(j)
        A[i, j] = (alpha * x * y + beta * x**2 + gamma * y**2, 1, 0)
```

So basically, there's a mapping between (i, j) and the 3 values of that value (this is for visualization).
I'd like to roll this up and somehow vectorize this, but I'm not sure how to or if I can. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the vectorized version:

```
i = arange(255)
j = arange(255)
x = simple_func1(i)
y = simple_func2(j)
y = y.reshape(-1,1)    

A = alpha * x * y + beta * x**2 + gamma * y**2 # broadcasting is your friend here
```

If you want to fill the last coordinates with 1 and 0:

```
B = empty(A.shape+(3,))
B[:,:,0] = A
B[:,:,1] = 1 # broadcasting again
B[:,:,2] = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to change simple_funcN so that they take arrays as input, and create arrays as output. After that, you could look into the numpy.meshgrid() or [the cartesian() function here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208118/using-numpy-to-build-an-array-of-all-combinations-of-two-arrays) to build coordinate arrays. After that, you should be able to use the coordinate array(s) to fill A with a one-liner.