# Constructing a 3D cube of points from a list

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list `pts` containing `N` points (Python floats).  I wish to construct a NumPy array of dimension `N*N*N*3` such that the array is equivalent to:

```
for i in xrange(0, N):
    for j in xrange(0, N):
        for k in xrange(0, N):
            arr[i,j,k,0] = pts[i]
            arr[i,j,k,1] = pts[j]
            arr[i,j,k,2] = pts[k]
```

I am wondering how I can exploit the array broadcasting rules of NumPy and functions such as `tile` to simplify this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the following should work:

```
pts = np.array(pts)  #Skip if pts is a numpy array already
lp = len(pts)
arr = np.zeros((lp,lp,lp,3))
arr[:,:,:,0] = pts[:,None,None]  #None is the same as np.newaxis
arr[:,:,:,1] = pts[None,:,None]
arr[:,:,:,2] = pts[None,None,:]
```

A quick test:

```
import numpy as np
import timeit

def meth1(pts):
   pts = np.array(pts)  #Skip if pts is a numpy array already
   lp = len(pts)
   arr = np.zeros((lp,lp,lp,3))
   arr[:,:,:,0] = pts[:,None,None]  #None is the same as np.newaxis
   arr[:,:,:,1] = pts[None,:,None]
   arr[:,:,:,2] = pts[None,None,:]
   return arr

def meth2(pts):
   lp = len(pts)
   N = lp
   arr = np.zeros((lp,lp,lp,3))
   for i in xrange(0, N):
      for j in xrange(0, N):
         for k in xrange(0, N):
            arr[i,j,k,0] = pts[i]
            arr[i,j,k,1] = pts[j]
            arr[i,j,k,2] = pts[k]

   return arr

pts = range(10)
a1 = meth1(pts)
a2 = meth2(pts)

print np.all(a1 == a2)

NREPEAT = 10000
print timeit.timeit('meth1(pts)','from __main__ import meth1,pts',number=NREPEAT)
print timeit.timeit('meth2(pts)','from __main__ import meth2,pts',number=NREPEAT)
```

results in:

```
True
0.873255968094   #my way
11.4249279499    #original
```

So this new method is an order of magnitude faster as well.

Comment: +1 -- Nice answer! Note that `numpy.ix_` does some of the above more automatically.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
N = 10
pts = xrange(0,N)
l = [ [ [ [ pts[i],pts[j],pts[k] ]  for k in xrange(0,N) ] for j in xrange(0,N) ] for i in xrange(0,N) ]
x = np.array(l, np.int32)
print x.shape # (10,10,10,3)
```

Comment: I had no idea that `xrange` was indexable.  That's kind of nifty.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in two lines:

```
def meth3(pts):
    arrs = np.broadcast_arrays(*np.ix_(pts, pts, pts))
    return np.concatenate([a[...,None] for a in arrs], axis=3)
```

However, this method is not as fast as [mgilson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12955035/577088)'s answer, because `concatenate` is annoyingly slow. A generalized version of his answer performs roughly as well, though, and can generate the result you want (i.e. an n-dimensional cartesian product contained within an n-dimensional grid) for any set of arrays.

```
def meth4(arrs):     # or meth4(*arrs) for a simplified interface
    arr = np.empty([len(a) for a in arrs] + [len(arrs)])
    for i, a in enumerate(np.ix_(*arrs)):
        arr[...,i] = a
    return arr
```

This accepts any sequence of sequences, as long as it can be converted into a sequence of numpy arrays:

```
>>> meth4([[0, 1], [2, 3]])
array([[[ 0.,  2.],
        [ 0.,  3.]],

       [[ 1.,  2.],
        [ 1.,  3.]]])
```

And the cost of this generality isn't too high -- it's only twice as slow for small `pts` arrays:

```
>>> (meth4([pts, pts, pts]) == meth1(pts)).all()
True
>>> %timeit meth4([pts, pts, pts])
10000 loops, best of 3: 27.4 us per loop
>>> %timeit meth1(pts)
100000 loops, best of 3: 13.1 us per loop
```

And it's actually a bit faster for larger ones (although the speed gain is probably due to my use of `empty` instead of `zeros`):

```
>>> pts = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
>>> %timeit meth4([pts, pts, pts])
100 loops, best of 3: 13.4 ms per loop
>>> %timeit meth1(pts)
100 loops, best of 3: 16.7 ms per loop
```

Comment: very nice.  I always find that `numpy.ix_` is a little too dense for me to really grok (though I haven't tried to wrap my head around it too hard).  To generalize, I would find it easier to construct tuples of length N, filled with `None` at every element except "i" (which would be `slice()`).  I would use that to index `pts` and then use ellipsis on the LHS as you did.  e.g. `idx = tuple(None if i==j else slice() for j in xrange(N)); arr[...,i] = pts[idx]`.

Comment: It took me a while to grok `numpy.ix_` as well, until one day I accidentally reinvented it. But it's basically exactly what you do above; `ix_(pts, pts, pts)` just returns the tuple `(pts[:,None,None], pts[None,:,None], pts[None,None,:])`.

Comment: Oh -- Well then, I suppose that makes it easier for me to remember as well since I basically reinvented it as well ... Now I understand your solution better (Thanks).  From an API standpoint, I'd probably define `meth4` as `def meth4(*arrs)` though.  Then you call it as `meth4(pts,pts,pts)` instead of `meth4((pts,pts,pts))`.  It just seems a little cleaner to me.

Comment: What prevents arr[...,:] = np.ix_(*arrs) from working in place of an explicit for loop?  (I've tried it and get an error regarding assigning an array element with a sequence.)

Comment: @FreddieWitherden, the basic answer is that the value returned by `np.ix_(*arrs)` is not a `numpy` array. It's a tuple of arrays, each of which has a different shape, so `numpy` can't work with it directly. Furthermore, given `ix = np.ix_(*arrs)`, `arr[...,i] = ix[0]` does something quite different from `arr[...,i] = ix[1]`, because `ix[0]` and `ix[1]` have different shapes, and so the broadcasting rules are applied differently. Finally, `arr[...,:]` and `arr[:,:,:,:]` are the same; `numpy` doesn't distinguish strongly between ellipses and slices, so it can't tell which axis to run over.