# pick combinations from multiple lists

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to python and I am struggling to form a combination of multiple lists. So, I have three (and possible more) looking like this:

```
uk_rock_stars=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
uk_pop_stars=[10,11,12,13,1,4,6,22,81]
us_stars=[22,34,44,7,33,99,22,77,99]
.
.
```

with all lists of the same length. Now, I would like to generate a combination list of them, with N being the total number of lists above. I am looking for a result looking like:

```
comb=[(1,10,22),(1,10,34),(1,10,44)...etc (all combinations)....]
```

such that, each combinations, say (1,10,22) is of same length as the number of original lists (in this case 3)

Comment: itertools and the like: http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.product

Comment: What you are asking is essentially what is called a Cartesian product. Although itertools is great for this, as suggested below, it is not the fastest approach if you have very long lists. See alternatives and speed comparisons at https://stackoverflow.com/a/11146645/7382307

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Read over this http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product, it explains everything.

`itertools` is a package that has a bunch of useful functionality for iterating over collections.  One useful feature is the `product` function which creates a generator that will iterate over the cartesian product of any number of iterable collections you give it.

The result of `itertools.product` is not a list, it is a generator.  A python generator is similar to a coroutine in other languages.  This means it will compute your combinations on an as needed basis.  If you compute the product of three iterables that each have size 100, but you only use the first 10 or so, `itertools.product` will only compute 10 combinations instead of computing all 100^3 combinations.

If you actually want a list object instead of a generator (maybe you want to compute slices or something) call the `list` function and pass your generator object as an argument.

The following code produces all combinations and prints the results.

**Code:**

```
import itertools

uk_rock_stars=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
uk_pop_stars=[10,11,12,13,1,4,6,22,81]
us_stars=[22,34,44,7,33,99,22,77,99]

for combination in itertools.product(uk_rock_stars, uk_pop_stars, us_stars):
    print combination
```

**Outputs:**

```
(1, 10, 22)
(1, 10, 34)
(1, 10, 44)
(1, 10, 7)
(1, 10, 33)
(1, 10, 99)
(1, 10, 22)
(1, 10, 77)
(1, 10, 99)
(1, 11, 22)
(1, 11, 34)
(1, 11, 44)
(1, 11, 7)
(1, 11, 33)
(1, 11, 99)
(1, 11, 22)
(1, 11, 77)
(1, 11, 99)
...
etc.
```

Answer (score 5):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
import itertools
comb = itertools.product(uk_rock_stars, uk_pop_stars, us_stars)
```

It will give you an iterator object, which may or may not be what you want. To convert it to a normal list, just use this:

```
comb = list(comb)
```