# How to get all combination from multiple lists?

Tags: python

I am not sure that my question is correct but I don't know how to explain it otherwords.
So I've got some lists like

```
a = ['11', '12']
b = ['21', '22']
c = ['31', '32']
```

And i need to get something like:

```
result = [
    ['11', '21', '31'],
    ['11', '21', '32'],
    ['11', '22', '31'],
    ['11', '22', '32'],
    ['12', '21', '31'],
    ['12', '21', '32'],
    ['12', '22', '31'],
    ['12', '22', '32']
]
```

Comment: Duplicate: [pick combinations from multiple lists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15305719/1324033)

Comment: Please try to research your problem yourself first, copying your question title into google produces multiple duplicates.

Comment: Will all of the lists be of length two if so it looks like a binary counting system so you could do that with an algorithm, but the post using itertools is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

User `itertools`, [combinations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
import itertools
a = ['11', '12']
b = ['21', '22']
c = ['31', '32']
list(itertools.combinations(itertools.chain(a,b,c), 3))
[('11', '12', '21'), ('11', '12', '22'), ('11', '12', '31'), ('11', '12', '32'), ('11', '21', '22'), ('11', '21', '31'), ('11', '21', '32'), ('11', '22', '31'), ('11', '22', '32'), ('11', '31', '32'), ('12', '21', '22'), ('12', '21', '31'), ('12', '21', '32'), ('12', '22', '31'), ('12', '22', '32'), ('12', '31', '32'), ('21', '22', '31'), ('21', '22', '32'), ('21', '31', '32'), ('22', '31', '32')]
```

or [product](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
list(itertools.product(a,b,c))
[('11', '21', '31'), ('11', '21', '32'), ('11', '22', '31'), ('11', '22', '32'), ('12', '21', '31'), ('12', '21', '32'), ('12', '22', '31'), ('12', '22', '32')]
```

Comment: `combinations` leaves some results that uses 2 elements of the same list.

Answer (score 7):

You need [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)
which returns cartesian product of input iterables.

```
>>> a = ['11', '12']
>>> b = ['21', '22']
>>> c = ['31', '32']
>>>
>>> from itertools import product
>>>
>>> list(product(a,b,c))
[('11', '21', '31'), ('11', '21', '32'), ('11', '22', '31'), ('11', '22', '32'), ('12', '21', '31'), ('12', '21', '32'), ('12', '22', '31'), ('12', '22', '32')]
```

And you can use a list comprehension to convert tuples to lists:

```
>>> [list(i) for i in product(a,b,c)]
[['11', '21', '31'], ['11', '21', '32'], ['11', '22', '31'], ['11', '22', '32'], ['12', '21', '31'], ['12', '21', '32'], ['12', '22', '31'], ['12', '22', '32']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools
list(itertools.product(a,b,c))
```

Or using numpy

```
import numpy
[list(x) for x in numpy.array(numpy.meshgrid(a,b,c)).T.reshape(-1,len(a))]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np    
np.array(np.meshgrid(a, b, c)).T.reshape(-1,3)
```

**edit**

```
import numpy as np 
len = 3 #combination array length
np.array(np.meshgrid(a, b, c)).T.reshape(-1,len)
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution without using any library:

```
def subproblem(list_a, list_b):
    c = list()
    for i, a_i in enumerate(list_a):
        for j, b_j in enumerate(list_b):
            c.append(a_i + [b_j])
    return c


def multi_lists_find_all_combination(lists):
    com = [[]]
    if len(lists) == 1:
        return lists[0]
    for i in range(0, len(lists)):
        print(i)
        com = subproblem(com, lists[i])
    return com

a = ['11', '12']
b = ['21', '22']
c = ['31', '32']

ans = multi_lists_find_all_combination([a,b,c])
```