# Alternative to triple nested loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop, nested

```
url_list = ['www.scrape.com/file1', 'www.scrape.com/file2', ''www.scrape.com/file3'] 

category_id_list = ['12345','abcde','ABCDE']

zip_list = ['10075','10017','10028']
```

I have three variables I use to create a URL to be requested.
in the order: url_list+zip+categoryid

the url is then passed into a function which has the scrape code

I was using 3 for loops to iterate over these lists but that is highly redundant

```
for url_ in url_list:
   for category_id in category_id_list:
       for zip_ in zip_list:

           request_url = url_+category_zip_
           func(request_url)
```

This does the job, but is there a more optimal way to do it? Thank you!

Comment: have you looked in to `itertools`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pick combinations from multiple lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15305719/pick-combinations-from-multiple-lists)

Comment: Consider using https://codereview.stackexchange.com when looking to improve a working implementation.

Answer (score 3):

You may use [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

```
import itertools

for url in (str.join("",url) for url in itertools.product(url_list,category_id_list,zip_list)):
    func(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit late, but this is the way I did it:

```
cats = ["a","b","c","d"]

zips = ["25320","53902","59607","53123"]

base = "https://example.com"

for i in range(4):
   url = "{}/{}/{}".format(base, cats[i], zips[i])
   print(url)
```

Output:

```
https://example.com/a/25320
https://example.com/b/53902
https://example.com/c/59607
https://example.com/d/53123
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to avoid writing multiple for loops is using [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip).It allows you to access ith element from each list at once. So you can do something like:

```
url_list = ['www.scrape.com/file1', 'www.scrape.com/file2', 'www.scrape.com/file3']
category_id_list = ['12345','abcde','ABCDE']
zip_list = ['10075','10017','10028']

for url, id, zip in zip(url_list, category_id_list, zip_list):
    request_url = url + id + zip
    func(request_url)
```