# Accessing coordinates within multidimensional arrays - python

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, indexing, coordinates

I am looking to put the x and y values of the coordinate grid into their own separate arrays in order to perform functions such as Pythagoras etc.
Here's my code below.

```
x1d = np.linspace(-xlen,xlen,res)
y1d = np.linspace(-ylen,ylen,res)
from itertools import product
coordinates = list(product(x1d, y1d))
xcoord = coordinates[:][:][0]

print np.shape(coordinates), np.shape(xcoord), coordinates
```

I get that the below code will give me

```
coordinates = [[x1,y1],[x2,y2],...,[xn,yn]].
```

How would one go about extracting the following arrays?

```
xcoord = [x1,x2,...,xn]
ycoord = [x1,x2,...,xn]
```

Is this the right solution for generating a 2D grid of points where I can perform functions upon each individual x,y point, assigning a resultant value to that point?

Thanks!

Comment: The code you have will not do what you think it will. Take a look at the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144513/numpy-cartesian-product-of-x-and-y-array-points-into-single-array-of-2d-points

Answer (score 2):

You could also use itertools to get your x and y values:

```
import itertools
x,y=itertools.izip(*coordinates)

# x=(x1,x2,...,xn)
# y=(y1,y2,...,yn)
```

In regards to the grid, have a look at numpy's [meshgrid](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) which could be useful for you. You can use it like so (taken from the example on the linked website):

```
x=np.arange(-5,5,.1)

y=np.arange(-5,5,.1)

xx,yy=meshgrid(x,y,sparse=True)

xx,yy=np.meshgrid(x,y,sparse=True)

z = np.sin(xx**2 + yy**2) / (xx**2 + yy**2)

h = plt.contourf(x,y,z)
```

[image: Numpy's meshgrid]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Shivan Why not? If I do `x,y=itertools.izip(zip(range(10),range(10,20))` i get `x=(0,1,2,...)` and `y=(10,11,...)` which I think is what has been asked...

Comment: @Shivan I added some words around it... I hope this is clearer now

Answer (score 0):

Treating it as a normal list, you can use a list comprehension:

```
xcord, ycord = [e[0] for e in coordinates], [e[1] for e in coordinates]
```

Hope this helps!