# Get all combinations of elements from two lists?

Tags: python, pandas

If I have two lists

```
l1 = ['A', 'B']

l2 = [1, 2]
```

what is the most elegant way to get a pandas data frame which looks like:

```
+-----+-----+-----+
|     | l1  | l2  |
+-----+-----+-----+
|  0  | A   | 1   |
+-----+-----+-----+
|  1  | A   | 2   |
+-----+-----+-----+
|  2  | B   | 1   |
+-----+-----+-----+
|  3  | B   | 2   |
+-----+-----+-----+
```

Note, the first column is the index.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

use [`product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) from `itertools`:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> pd.DataFrame(list(product(l1, l2)), columns=['l1', 'l2'])
  l1  l2
0  A   1
1  A   2
2  B   1
3  B   2
```

Comment: thank you it works, i also modified something better

``from itertools import product

filter_df = pd.DataFrame(list(product((df['l1'].unique()).tolist(), (df['l2'].unique()).tolist())), columns=['l1', 'l2'])``

Answer (score 23):

As an alternative you can use pandas' `cartesian_product` (may be more useful with large numpy arrays):

```
In [11]: lp1, lp2 = pd.core.reshape.util.cartesian_product([l1, l2])

In [12]: pd.DataFrame(dict(l1=lp1, l2=lp2))
Out[12]:
  l1  l2
0  A   1
1  A   2
2  B   1
3  B   2
```

*This seems a little messy to read in to a DataFrame with the correct orient...*

Note: previously `cartesian_product` was located at `pd.core.reshape.util.cartesian_product`.

Comment: *atm there is a pd.MultiIndex.from_product, not sure how useful DataFrame constructor would be...*

Comment: As of pandas 0.20.2, `cartesian_product()` is in `pd.core.reshape.util`. This solution is faster than using `itertools.product`, and can be made even faster by initializing the dataframe with `np.array().T` of the non-unpacked data instead.

Comment: This is an elegant solution and works just as easily for 3+ lists. I just used it quickly to find all combinations of 5 lists. Very nice!

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the `sklearn` library, which uses a NumPy-based approach:

```
from sklearn.utils.extmath import cartesian

df = pd.DataFrame(cartesian((L1, L2)))
```

For more verbose but possibly more efficient variants see [Numpy: cartesian product of x and y array points into single array of 2D points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144513/numpy-cartesian-product-of-x-and-y-array-points-into-single-array-of-2d-points).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `merge`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(l1, columns=['l1'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(l2, columns=['l2'])

df1.merge(df2, how='cross')
```

Output:

```
  l1  l2
0  A   1
1  A   2
2  B   1
3  B   2
```