# Pandas initialize dataframe with np.array().T

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I came across Ken Wei's comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636395/8741781) stating that using pandas `cartesian_product()` while initializing the dataframe with `np.array().T` is faster than `itertools.product` for combining elements of two lists.

I'm confused as to how it would be used. Given two lists:

```
l1 = ['A', 'B']

l2 = [1, 2]
```

How would you arrive at this dataframe using his `cartesian_product()` and `np.array().T`?

```
+-----+-----+-----+
|     | l1  | l2  |
+-----+-----+-----+
|  0  | A   | 1   |
+-----+-----+-----+
|  1  | A   | 2   |
+-----+-----+-----+
|  2  | B   | 1   |
+-----+-----+-----+
|  3  | B   | 2   |
+-----+-----+-----+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which means, as stated, not unpacking but rather using `np.array().T`:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(np.array(pd.core.reshape.util.cartesian_product([l1, l2])).T)
   0  1
0  A  1
1  A  2
2  B  1
3  B  2
```