# Pythonic way to write a loop

Tags: python, list, loops

I have two lists: `a = [1, 2, 3]` and `b = [4, 5, 6]`.

I have used two loops in python to subtract each element of `b` from each element of `a`.

```
import numpy as np
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]
p = -1
result = np.zeros(len(a)*len(a))
for i in range(0,len(a)):
    for j in range(0,len(a)):
        p = p + 1
        result[p] = a[i] - b[j]
```

My result is correct: `result = [-3., -4., -5., -2., -3., -4., -1., -2., -3.]`.

However, I would like to know if there is more elegant('pythonic') way to do it.

Comment: you havnt provided ur whole code

Comment: Instead of making it more "pythonic", which is a ridiculous idea, make this code much easier to read. Start by making the variable names way more meaningful.

Comment: @Puciek Cannot understand what you mean because I thing it is pretty clear. iF not, correct me.

Comment: @DimKoim you mean that variables named "i" and "j" are clear? I must have forgotten my decoder ring then.

Comment: @Puciek Because for sure you are way more expert than me, please show me the way how i,j variables can be clear. Much appreciated from a very beginner programmer. Thank you.

Comment: @DimKoim well, the question is - what are they supposed to represent? Name should relate to that. So if a variable holds the letter "J", then name "j" is fine, but if it is holding a part of an list, then it should convey the name of element in question, in this case "number" would be a sorta-ok name. But trouble in naming "i" or "j" comes from the fact that lists are named "a" and "b", and thus we have no idea what are they representing. Have a read of the middle part here for an example of variable refactoring, and how much it matters: http://tinyurl.com/oasu2q2

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no need to use an index. You can iterate over the values.

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]
result = []
for x in a:
    for y in b:
        result.append(x - y)
```

The pythonic way would be a list comprehension.

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]
result = [x - y for x in a for y in b]
```

Please bear in mind that you should use meaningful names for `a`, `b`, `x`and `y` in real code.

Comment: I would implement it using the list comprehension. I think it's the most Pythonic, since it uses functional programming where it's appropriate.

Answer (score 5):

Pythonic way will be to use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), as it returns Cartesian product of the iterables passed to it. As no Python loop is involved it is going to be fast compared to version that are using loop:

```
>>> from operator import sub
>>> from itertools import starmap, product
>>> list(starmap(sub, product(a, b)))
[-3, -4, -5, -2, -3, -4, -1, -2, -3]
```

In NumPy you can do this using the recipes mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11146645/846892):

```
>>> arr = np.dstack(np.meshgrid(a, b)).reshape(-1, 2)
>>> np.subtract(arr[:,0], arr[:,1])
array([-3, -2, -1, -4, -3, -2, -5, -4, -3])
```

Timing comparisons:

```
>>> b = [4, 5, 6]*1000
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]*1000
>>> %timeit list(starmap(sub, product(a, b)))
1 loops, best of 3: 464 ms per loop
>>> %timeit [x - y for x in a for y in b]
1 loops, best of 3: 491 ms per loop
>>> %%timeit                                 
result = []
for x in a:
    for y in b:
        result.append(x - y) #attribute lookup is slow
... 
1 loops, best of 3: 908 ms per loop
>>> %%timeit
result = [];append = result.append 
for x in a:
    for y in b:
        append(x - y)
... 
1 loops, best of 3: 617 ms per loop
#Numpy version will be little faster if a and b were nd arrays.
>>> %timeit arr = np.dstack(np.meshgrid(a, b)).reshape(-1, 2);np.subtract(arr[:,0], arr[:,1])
1 loops, best of 3: 573 ms per loop
```

Comment: I get 147ms for my `repeat/tile` hack and your data `OP*1000`

Comment: @qarma I agree it is the fastest one of the lot. +1(Got 265ms on my system)

Answer (score 5):

Since you are using `numpy` already, it's as simple as this:

```
In [29]: numpy.repeat(a, len(b)) - numpy.tile(b, len(a))
Out[29]: array([-3, -4, -5, -2, -3, -4, -1, -2, -3])
```

Per request in comments, OP wants 1d output size N^2 (although 2d might be more natural), for that numpy provides convenient functions to extend N-sized array to N^M, namely `repeat` and `tile`:

```
numpy.repeat([1,0], 2)
array([1, 1, 0, 0])

numpy.tile([1,0], 2)
array([1, 0, 1, 0])
```

Once both `a` and `b` are reformatted to the shape of `p`, it's a matter of element-wise subtraction that's native in `numpy`.

Comment: This is clever and performant, but you should explain how it works.