# combine numpy arrays element by element?

Tags: python, numpy, cartesian-product

I'm not sure what the proper terminology is for this but I would like to combine two arrays such that the resulting array has paired each item from A with each item from B:

```
A = [1, 2, 3]
B = [1, 2, 3]

result = [[1,1],
          [1,2],
          [1,3],
          [2,1],
          [2,2],
          [2,3],
          [3,1],
          [3,2],
          [3,3]]
```

Is there a numpy method for accomplishing this or do I need to generate a for loop and build a whole new array?

Comment: Not within numpy, but within itertools (itertools.product).

Comment: Related: [Numpy: cartesian product of x and y array points into single array of 2D points](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144513/numpy-cartesian-product-of-x-and-y-array-points-into-single-array-of-2d-points)

Answer (score 2):

Generate that using:

```
[(x,y) for x in A for y in B]
```