# find all monomial with certain number of variable and degree

Tags: python, algorithm

suppose we have a list like [x,y,z] and a number like 2.
i need an algorithm to find all monomials with this 3 variable and degree=2

my algorithm:

```
def mul(x:list, y:list) -> list:
        return ["".join(elm) for elm in product(x, y)]

def f(x:list, n:int) -> list:
    r = x;
    for i in range(n-1):
        r = mul(r, x)
    return r

>>> f(['x','y','z'],2)
['xx', 'xy', 'xz', 'yx', 'yy', 'yz', 'zx', 'zy', 'zz']
```

is there any better algorithm to do this?

**EDIT:**

1) suppose 'xz' != 'zx'
2) suppose 'xx' = 'x^2'

Comment: The question is too broad. One can imagine lots of algorithms to do this and it is not clear what are the desired properties of an algorithm you are looking for. (Do you really need ALL the algorithms that solve this problem?) Please, clarify.

Comment: sorry, i need to do this with a better algorithm, i cant find any other solution for my problem.

Comment: What do you mean by 'better'? What are your exact requirements? Do you need faster algorithm? How fast should it be?

Comment: @IlyaV.Schurov lowest time complexity!

Comment: I doubt there is any way to do it faster then `itertools.product` (which is designed exactly for solving this problem), like in the answer by vishes_shell.

Comment: @IlyaV.Schurov i'm looking for another algorithm without product...

Comment: After all, your problem is equivalent to the problem of calculating the Cartesian power of some finite set. `itertools.product` is created for exactly this kind of problems and solve it rather efficiently. Maybe, you can try some approaches discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144513/numpy-cartesian-product-of-x-and-y-array-points-into-single-array-of-2d-points — but it seems they are slower than `itertools.product` for small arrays.

Answer (score 3):

I believe what you're looking for is called [`product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) from [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) module

```
from itertools import product

a=product(['x','y','z'], repeat=2)
list(map(lambda x: ''.join(x), a))
```

Output:

```
['xx', 'xy', 'xz', 'yx', 'yy', 'yz', 'zx', 'zy', 'zz']
```

Comment: I need another algorithm to do this.anyway  your answer is very good, thanks