# Extract interior points of polygon given the exterior coordinates

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely

I have a list of boundary coordinates for a polygon. I want to extract some interior points from this polygon based on some sort of grid spacing that I can choose.

For example, say I have this:

```
from shapely.geometry import MultiPoint
Polygon([(0,0),
        (1,0),
        (1,1),
        (0,1)])
```

[image]

This yields a simple square. However, we can imagine this square is actually a grid filled with an infinite number of points. For this example, let's say I want a list of points inside the square at 0.1 grid spacing. Is there a way to extract a list of these points?

For bonus points, how would we not only get the interior points, but also all of the boundary points at 0.1 grid spacing?

Edit: This question was mainly posed for non-rectangular shapes and has the purpose of finding points for shapes of counties/provinces/districts, etc. I just used a rectangle as a simple example. However, I accepted the proposed solution. Will give out upvotes to anyone who provides a more complex solution for non-rectangular objects

Comment: (Bonus points) In the last paragraph, they call it bounties here. ;p

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get all lattice points lying inside a Shapely polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44399749/get-all-lattice-points-lying-inside-a-shapely-polygon)

Comment: do you need something that would generalize to an arbitrary shape? What would the solution for a hexagon look like?

Comment: Yes. It would be nice to have a solution that works for non-rectangular shapes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Regarding to the extraction of the **interior points**, based on a grid shape, it can be done with simple math, like so :

```py
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, MultiPoint
from math import ceil

# The setup
pol = Polygon([(0,0), (1,0), (1,1), (0,1)])
cell_size = 0.1

# Extract coordinates of the bounding box:
minx, miny, maxx, maxy = pol.bounds

# How many points in each dimension ?
rows = int(ceil((maxy - miny) / cell_size))
cols = int(ceil((maxx - minx) / cell_size))

# Actually generate the points:
pts = []
x, y = minx, miny
for countcols in range(cols):
    for countrows in range(rows):
        pts.append((x, y))
        y += cell_size
    x += cell_size
    y = miny

# Create the MultiPoint from this list
result_pts_interior = MultiPoint(pts)
```

Result:

[image: Result1]

But note that if the polygon does not have a rectangular shape, it will also generate points which will be outside the polygon (you should then test if they intersect the polygon with `pol.intersects(Point(x, y))` before adding them to the list).

---

- Regarding to the extraction of **boundary points**, it can be done using the `interpolate` method of shapely LineStrings, like so :

```py
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, MultiPoint
import numpy as np

# The setup
pol = Polygon([(0,0), (1,0), (1,1), (0,1)])
distance_between_pts = 0.1

boundary = pol.boundary # Boundary of polygon as a linestring
boundary_length = boundary.length # Its length
# Build a list of points spaced by 0.1 along this linestring:
pts_boundary = [
    boundary.interpolate(n, False) for n
    in np.linspace(0, boundary_length, int(boundary_length / distance_between_pts) + 1)
]
# Create the MultiPoint from this list
result_pts_boundary = MultiPoint(pts_boundary)
```

Result:

[image: Result2]