# Fastest way to produce a grid of points that fall within a polygon or shape?

Tags: python, coordinates, polygon, points, shapely

I am using shapely in python and trying to generate evenly spaced points in a grid that fall within a shape in the fastest O(n) time. The shape may be any closed polygon, not just a square or circle. My current approach is:

1. Find min/max y & x to build a rectangle.
2. Build a grid of points given a spacing parameter (resolution)
3. Verify one-by-one if the points fall within the shape.

Is there a faster way to do this?

```
# determine maximum edges
polygon = shape(geojson['features'][i]['geometry'])
latmin, lonmin, latmax, lonmax = polygon.bounds

# construct a rectangular mesh
points = []
for lat in np.arange(latmin, latmax, resolution):
    for lon in np.arange(lonmin, lonmax, resolution):
        points.append(Point((round(lat,4), round(lon,4))))

# validate if each point falls inside shape
valid_points.extend([i for i in points if polygon.contains(i)])
```

[image: example shape and points]

Comment: Are the shapes always convex? If they are you can probably just check the outer points.

Comment: Does that polygon.contains() accept numpy arrays? If it does, you can use numpy.meshdrid to create two matrix for x and y coordinates, witch would be faster than iterate

Comment: np.meshgrid IS faster, however shape.contains does NOT take  numpy arrays it would seem. you have sped up my software.

Comment: Related questions: [Get all lattice points lying inside a Shapely polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44399749/7851470), [Extract interior points of polygon given the exterior coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65850719/7851470).

Comment: what library the `shape` function belongs to ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I saw that you answered your question (and seems to be happy with using intersection) but also note that `shapely` (and the underlying `geos` library) have *prepared geometries* for more efficient batch operations on some predicates (contains, contains_properly, covers, and intersects).
See [Prepared geometry operations](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#prepared-geometry-operations).

Adapted from the code in your question, it could be used like so:

```
from shapely.prepared import prep

# determine maximum edges
polygon = shape(geojson['features'][i]['geometry'])
latmin, lonmin, latmax, lonmax = polygon.bounds

# create prepared polygon
prep_polygon = prep(polygon)

# construct a rectangular mesh
points = []
for lat in np.arange(latmin, latmax, resolution):
    for lon in np.arange(lonmin, lonmax, resolution):
        points.append(Point((round(lat,4), round(lon,4))))

# validate if each point falls inside shape using
# the prepared polygon
valid_points.extend(filter(prep_polygon.contains, points))
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh why hell yes. Use the intersection method of shapely.

```
polygon = shape(geojson['features'][i]['geometry'])
lonmin, latmin, lonmax, latmax = polygon.bounds

# construct rectangle of points
x, y = np.round(np.meshgrid(np.arange(lonmin, lonmax, resolution), np.arange(latmin, latmax, resolution)),4)
points = MultiPoint(list(zip(x.flatten(),y.flatten())))

# validate each point falls inside shapes
valid_points.extend(list(points.intersection(polygon)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The best i can think is do this:

```
X,Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(latmin, latmax, resolution),
              np.arange(lonmin, lonmax, resolution))

#create a iterable with the (x,y) coordinates
points = zip(X.flatten(),Y.flatten())

valid_points.extend([i for i in points if polygon.contains(i)])
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to generate `n` points in a `shapely.geometry.Polygon`, there is a simple iterative function to do it. Manage `tol` (tolerance) argument to speed up the points generation.

```
import numpy as np
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon


def gen_n_point_in_polygon(self, n_point, polygon, tol = 0.1):
    """
    -----------
    Description
    -----------
    Generate n regular spaced points within a shapely Polygon geometry
    -----------
    Parameters
    -----------
    - n_point (int) : number of points required
    - polygon (shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon) : Polygon geometry
    - tol (float) : spacing tolerance (Default is 0.1)
    -----------
    Returns
    -----------
    - points (list) : generated point geometries
    -----------
    Examples
    -----------
    >>> geom_pts = gen_n_point_in_polygon(200, polygon)
    >>> points_gs = gpd.GeoSeries(geom_pts)
    >>> points_gs.plot()
    """
    # Get the bounds of the polygon
    minx, miny, maxx, maxy = polygon.bounds    
    # ---- Initialize spacing and point counter
    spacing = polygon.area / n_point
    point_counter = 0
    # Start while loop to find the better spacing according to tolérance increment
    while point_counter <= n_point:
        # --- Generate grid point coordinates
        x = np.arange(np.floor(minx), int(np.ceil(maxx)), spacing)
        y = np.arange(np.floor(miny), int(np.ceil(maxy)), spacing)
        xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x,y)
        # ----
        pts = [Point(X,Y) for X,Y in zip(xx.ravel(),yy.ravel())]
        # ---- Keep only points in polygons
        points = [pt for pt in pts if pt.within(polygon)]
        # ---- Verify number of point generated
        point_counter = len(points)
        spacing -= tol
    # ---- Return
    return points
```