# two numpy arrays into an array of pairwise arrays

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, pairwise

I would like to create a matrix of pairwise arrays from two arrays of different length, a and b:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3])

b = np.array([4,5,6,7])
```

So, c matrix should look like:

```
[[1,4], [1,5], [1,6], ..., [3,7]]
```

Comment: what is the language?

Comment: what is `np`  object?

Comment: The language is python and  numpy is imported as np

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Numpy: cartesian product of x and y array points into single array of 2D points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144513/numpy-cartesian-product-of-x-and-y-array-points-into-single-array-of-2d-points)

Answer (score 2):

```
c = [[i,j] for i in (a) for j in (b)]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.meshgrid()`.

```
a = np.array((1, 2, 3))
b = np.array((4, 5, 6, 7))
out = np.stack([each.ravel(order='F') for each in np.meshgrid(a, b)])
```

`out` now looks like this:

```
array([[1, 4],
   [1, 5],
   [1, 6],
   [1, 7],
   [2, 4],
   [2, 5],
   [2, 6],
   [2, 7],
   [3, 4],
   [3, 5],
   [3, 6],
   [3, 7]])
```

Comment: Why use `order='F'`?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `product` from `itertools` library. `product(a, b)` will return iterator product between `a` and `b`. Using `vstack` to make it an array.

```
from itertools import product
np.vstack(product(a, b))
```

**Output**

```
array([[1, 4], [1, 5], [1, 6], ...])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a 2D numpy array with your two arrays and then swap the axes of the combined array with np.swapaxes to acquire shape you want.

```
X = np.array([a, b])
swapped_array = X.swapaxes(1,0) 
# X.swapaxes(0,1) returns the same result
```