# Efficient flattening of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe. It looks like this:

```
pd.DataFrame(data=np.arange(1,10).reshape(3,3), index=['A', 'B', 'C'], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
```

but has 100 rows and 100 columns.

I want to flatten it, so that it looks like this:

```
pd.DataFrame({'row' : ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'], 'col' : ['A', 'B', 'C']*3, 'val' : np.arange(1,10)})
```

What's the most efficient way to do this?

Thanks,

Jack

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Option 1**
Not 100% sure on efficiency, but the simplest way to do this is with *`df.melt`*.

```
df.rename_axis('row')\
  .reset_index()\
  .melt('row', value_name='val', var_name='col')\
  .sort_values(['row', 'col'])

  row col  val
0   A   A    1
3   A   B    2
6   A   C    3
1   B   A    4
4   B   B    5
7   B   C    6
2   C   A    7
5   C   B    8
8   C   C    9
```

---

**Option 2**
Another simple option with *`stack`* -

```
v = df.stack().reset_index()
v.columns=['row', 'col', 'val']
v
```

Or,

```
df.stack().rename_axis(['row', 'col']).reset_index(name='val')
```

```
  row col  val
0   A   A    1
1   A   B    2
2   A   C    3
3   B   A    4
4   B   B    5
5   B   C    6
6   C   A    7
7   C   B    8
8   C   C    9
```

Answer (score 3):

**Method #1**

NumPy approach -

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/11146645/ @senderle
def cartesian_product(*arrays):
    la = len(arrays)
    dtype = np.result_type(*arrays)
    arr = np.empty([len(a) for a in arrays] + [la], dtype=dtype)
    for i, a in enumerate(np.ix_(*arrays)):
        arr[...,i] = a
    return arr.reshape(-1, la)

def flatten_dataframe(df):
    c = df.columns.values.astype(str)
    i = df.index.values.astype(str)
    df_out = pd.DataFrame(cartesian_product(i,c),columns=[['row','col']])
    df_out['val'] = df.values.ravel()
    return df_out
```

Sample run -

```
In [598]: df
Out[598]: 
   A  B  C
P  1  2  3
Q  4  5  6
R  7  8  9

In [599]: flatten_dataframe(df)
Out[599]: 
  row col  val
0   P   A    1
1   P   B    2
2   P   C    3
3   Q   A    4
4   Q   B    5
5   Q   C    6
6   R   A    7
7   R   B    8
8   R   C    9
```

**Method #2 : `object` dtype dataframe**

If you are okay with `object` dtype dataframe, here's another way -

```
def flatten_dataframe_obj(df):
    c = df.columns.values.astype(str)
    i = df.index.values.astype(str)
    m = len(i)
    n = len(c)
    out = np.empty((m,n,3),dtype=object)
    out[...,0] = i[:,None]
    out[...,1] = c
    out[...,2] = df.values
    return pd.DataFrame(out.reshape(-1,3), columns=[['row','col','val']])
```

Comment: Nice that I get to see some great numpy solutions to  pandas questions every now and then.

Answer (score 2):

This should be fast :-)

```
new_df=pd.DataFrame({'row':df.index.repeat(df.shape[1]),'col':df.columns.tolist()*len(df),'val':np.concatenate(df.values)})
new_df
Out[343]: 
  col row  val
0   A   A    1
1   B   A    2
2   C   A    3
3   A   B    4
4   B   B    5
5   C   B    6
6   A   C    7
7   B   C    8
8   C   C    9
```