# numpy: multidimensional linspace

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

`numpy.linspace` is one-dimensional linear gradient. For example: numpy.linspace(0, 3, 4):

```
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

It is easy to imagine 2-dimensional linear gradient:

```
[[[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0], [3, 0]],
 [[0, 1], [1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 1]],
 [[0, 2], [1, 2], [2, 2], [3, 2]],
 [[0, 3], [1, 3], [2, 3], [3, 3]]]
```

What I need is 3 or even 4-dimensional linear gradients using numpy.

I can easily achieve it using Python code, but it is too slow.

```
%time arr = numpy.array([
    [
        [
            (a, b, c)
            for a in range(65)
        ]
        for b in range(65)
    ]
    for c in range(65)
])
Wall time: 177 ms

arr.shape
(65, 65, 65, 3)
```

Comment: Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11144513/7207392). The question is 2D but some answers also do the ND case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are number of tools to do this - `np.meshgrid`, `np.indices`, etc

`numpy/lib/index_tricks.py` has a number of 'cute' functions and classes that do things like this:

```
In [387]: np.mgrid[0:3:4j, 0:3:4j]
Out[387]: 
array([[[0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [2., 2., 2., 2.],
        [3., 3., 3., 3.]],

       [[0., 1., 2., 3.],
        [0., 1., 2., 3.],
        [0., 1., 2., 3.],
        [0., 1., 2., 3.]]])
```

Swap the axes to get the layout you show:

```
In [391]: IJ.transpose(1,2,0)
Out[391]: 
array([[[0., 0.],
        [0., 1.],
        [0., 2.],
        [0., 3.]],

       [[1., 0.],
        [1., 1.],
        [1., 2.],
        [1., 3.]],

       [[2., 0.],
        [2., 1.],
        [2., 2.],
        [2., 3.]],

       [[3., 0.],
        [3., 1.],
        [3., 2.],
        [3., 3.]]])
In [392]: _.shape
Out[392]: (4, 4, 2)
```

Another one: `np.array(list(np.ndindex((4,4)))).reshape(4,4,2)`, or `np.array(list(itertools.product(range(4),range(4)))).reshape(4,4,2)`

Comment: numpy.mgrid do almost what I need. The small thing: the result should be transposed: `numpy.mgrid[0:4, 0:4, 0:4].T` gives exactly what I described. And thanks for j-magick! I actually need a normalized array and was going to divide values. With j this much more convenient and 4 times faster: `numpy.mgrid[0:1:4j, 0:1:4j, 0:1:4j].T`