# generating matrix of pairs from two object vectors using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two object arrays not necessarily of the same length:

```
import numpy as np

class Obj_A:
    def __init__(self,n):
        self.type = 'a'+str(n)
    def __eq__(self,other):
        return self.type==other.type

class Obj_B:
    def __init__(self,n):
        self.type = 'b'+str(n)
    def __eq__(self,other):
        return self.type==other.type

a = np.array([Obj_A(n) for n in range(2)])
b = np.array([Obj_B(n) for n in range(3)])
```

I would like to generate the matrix

```
mat = np.array([[[a[0],b[0]],[a[0],b[1]],[a[0],b[2]]],
                [[a[1],b[0]],[a[1],b[1]],[a[1],b[2]]]])
```

this matrix has shape `(len(a),len(b),2)`. Its elements are

```
mat[i,j] = [a[i],b[j]]
```

A solution is

```
mat = np.empty((len(a),len(b),2),dtype='object')
for i,aa in enumerate(a):
    for j,bb in enumerate(b): 
        mat[i,j] = np.array([aa,bb],dtype='object')
```

but this is too expensive for my problem, which has `O(len(a)) = O(len(b)) = 1e5`.

I suspect there is a clean numpy solution involving `np.repeat`, `np.tile` and `np.transpose`, similar to the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144513/numpy-cartesian-product-of-x-and-y-array-points-into-single-array-of-2d-points), but the output in this case does not simply reshape to the desired result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest using [`np.meshgrid()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html), which takes two input arrays and repeats both along different axes so that looking at corresponding positions of the outputs gets you all possible combinations. For example:

```
>>> x, y = np.meshgrid([1, 2, 3], [4, 5])
>>> x
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])
>>> y
array([[4, 4, 4],
       [5, 5, 5]])
```

In your case, you can put the two arrays together and transpose them into the proper configuration. Based on some experimentation I think this should work for you:

```
>>> np.transpose(np.meshgrid(a, b), (2, 1, 0))
```

Comment: Thanks David. This runs fast and will scale to the problem sizes I'm interested in. I don't fully understand the (2,1,0). Is there any easy way to see what's happening there?

Comment: That just tells `np.transpose()` how to permute the dimensions of the array. I'd suggest looking at [the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) and playing around with a few examples, e.g. make a 3D array `arr` and try `arr.transpose(0, 2, 1)`, `arr.transpose(2, 0, 1)`, and so on to see how it works.

Comment: For a 3d array, (2,1,0) is the default transpose order, so `np.transpose(np.meshgrid(a,b))` should be enough.  Another way to express it is `np.array(np.meshgrid(a,b)).T`