# Add rows to a df for IDs that don't have two groups in another column in Python

Tags: python

I have a large dataset with about 50 columns, but the columns of concern are listed below:

| ID | category | price | code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | A | 10 | 1 |
| 12 | B | 5 | 22 |
| 12 | A | 9 | 26 |
| 25 | B | 13 | 17 |
| 26 | A | 8 | 19 |
| 26 | B | 11 | 6 |

As you can see, some of my IDs have both categories A and B and some don’t. In my output table I want each ID to have both categories A and B and “blank” cells for missing prices and codes in the newly added rows. My desired output looks like this:

| ID | category | price | code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | A | 10 | 1 |
| 11 | B |  |  |
| 12 | A | 9 | 26 |
| 12 | B | 5 | 22 |
| 25 | A |  |  |
| 25 | B | 13 | 17 |
| 26 | A | 8 | 19 |
| 26 | B | 11 | 6 |

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Markdown tables are nice to look at but difficult to copy. Could you paste the result of applying `.head().to_dict()` to your table?

Comment: {'ID': {0: 13, 1: 22, 2: 22, 3: 32, 4: 33},
 'Category': {0: 4020,
  1: 4020,
  2: 4020,
  3: 4020,
  4: 4020},
 'Price': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 2},
 'Code': {0: 14,
  1: 39,

  2: 1,
  3: 53,
  4: 1},
 'Ranking: {0: 14.0,
  1: 15.0,
  2: 1.0,
  3: 31.0,
  4: 1.0},
.
.
.
.

Comment: Using `df.set_index(['ID','category']).reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(itertools.product(df.ID, df.category)))` as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53872957/2476977) gets close to what you want, but it results in repeated rows for some reason I don't understand

Comment: yeah it is not working well. But thanks anyway!

Comment: see my latest edit

Comment: I ran the code but it says "None of ['Category'] are in the columns"!

Comment: I suspect that's a capitalization issue. I've edited my answer so that the script is self contained and can run with a copy and paste.

Comment: Yes it is working! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

As in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52104737/2476977), you could do the following.

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd

data = {'ID': {0: 11, 1: 12, 2: 12, 3: 25, 4: 26, 5: 26},
    'Category': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'A', 3: 'B', 4: 'A', 5: 'B'},
    'Price': {0: 10, 1: 5, 2: 9, 3: 13, 4: 8, 5: 11},
    'Code': {0: 1, 1: 22, 2: 26, 3: 17, 4: 19, 5: 6}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.set_index(['ID','Category']).reindex(
    pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
        itertools.product(df.ID.unique(), df.Category.unique())))
```

The result:

```
                price  code
11  A          10      1   
    B             NaN   NaN
12  A          9       26  
    B          5       22  
25  A             NaN   NaN
    B          13      17  
26  A          8       19  
    B          11      6
```