# Create a dateTime for every ID in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame (namend df) from 2016/1/1 00:00 until 2018/11/25 23:00 with a timestamp every hour, object_id and a value. The data set only contains rows where an object_id has a value.

```
timestampHour     object_id  value
2016/1/1 00:00    1          2
2016/1/1 00:00    3          1
2016/1/1 01:00    1          1
2016/1/1 01:00    2          3
2016/1/1 02:00    2          3
2016/1/1 02:00    3          2
```

I would like to get a dataframe showing all object id's for every hour, with a null value if there is no value.

```
timestampHour     object_id  value
2016/1/1 00:00    1          2
2016/1/1 00:00    2          null
2016/1/1 00:00    3          1
2016/1/1 01:00    1          1
2016/1/1 01:00    2          3
2016/1/1 01:00    3          null
2016/1/1 02:00    1          null
2016/1/1 02:00    2          3
2016/1/1 02:00    3          2
```

I have created the dateTime from timestamps. And rounded them to hours with the following code:

```
df["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["result_timestamp"])
df['timestampHour'] = df['result_timestamp'].dt.round('60min')
```

(I don't know if there are better options, but I have been trying to create timestampHour rows until 12 (I have 12 every unique object_id) and fill those newly created rows with (the for that hour) unused object_id. But I have not been able to create the empty rows, with the condition)

I am fairly new to programming and I am not finding a clue to get closer to solving this problem from searching other posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `pivot_table` and `unstack`:

```
df.pivot_table(
    index='object_id',  columns='timestampHour', values='value'
).unstack().rename('value').reset_index()
```

```
    timestampHour  object_id  value
0  2016/1/1 00:00          1    2.0
1  2016/1/1 00:00          2    NaN
2  2016/1/1 00:00          3    1.0
3  2016/1/1 01:00          1    1.0
4  2016/1/1 01:00          2    3.0
5  2016/1/1 01:00          3    NaN
6  2016/1/1 02:00          1    NaN
7  2016/1/1 02:00          2    3.0
8  2016/1/1 02:00          3    2.0
```

---

To see why this works, the intermediate `pivot_table` is helpful to look at:

```
timestampHour  2016/1/1 00:00  2016/1/1 01:00  2016/1/1 02:00
object_id
1                         2.0             1.0             NaN
2                         NaN             3.0             3.0
3                         1.0             NaN             2.0
```

Where a value *is not* found for a combination of `object_id` and `timestampHour`, a `NaN` is added to the table.  When you use `unstack`, these `NaN`'s are kept, giving you the desired result with missing values represented.

Answer (score 0):

This is also `.reindex` with a cartesian product of the two levels. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144513/numpy-cartesian-product-of-x-and-y-array-points-into-single-array-of-2d-points) goes into detail on ways to optimize the performance of the product for large datasets.

```
import pandas as pd

id_cols = ['timestampHour', 'object_id']
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df[id_cols].apply(pd.Series.unique).values.T, names=id_cols)

df.set_index(id_cols).reindex(idx).reset_index()
```

#### Output:

```
    timestampHour  object_id  value
0  2016/1/1 00:00          1    2.0
1  2016/1/1 00:00          3    1.0
2  2016/1/1 00:00          2    NaN
3  2016/1/1 01:00          1    1.0
4  2016/1/1 01:00          3    NaN
5  2016/1/1 01:00          2    3.0
6  2016/1/1 02:00          1    NaN
7  2016/1/1 02:00          3    2.0
8  2016/1/1 02:00          2    3.0
```