# Cartesian product from 2 series

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have this big serie of length *t* (*t* = 200K rows)

prices = [200, 100, 500, 300 ..]

and I want to calculate a matrix (*t*X*t*) where a value is calculated as:

```
matrix[i][j] = prices[j]/prices[i] - 1
```

I tried this using a double for, but it's too slow. Any ideas how to perform it better?

```
for p0 in prices:
    for p1 in prices:
        matrix[i][j] = p1/p0 - 1
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144513/numpy-cartesian-product-of-x-and-y-array-points-into-single-array-of-2d-points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A vectorized solution is using [`np.meshgrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html), with `prices` and `1/prices` as arguments (note that prices must be an array), and multiplying the result and substracting `1` in order to compute `matrix[i][j] = prices[j]/prices[i] - 1`:

```
a, b = np.meshgrid(p, 1/p)
a * b - 1
```

As an example:

```
p = np.array([1,4,2])
```

Would give:

```
a, b = np.meshgrid(p, 1/p)
a * b - 1

array([[ 0.  ,  3.  ,  1.  ],
       [-0.75,  0.  , -0.5 ],
       [-0.5 ,  1.  ,  0.  ]])
```

Quick check of some of the cells:

```
(i,j)    prices[j]/prices[i] - 1
--------------------------------
(1,1)        1/1 - 1 = 0
(1,2)        4/1 - 1 = 3
(1,3)        2/1 - 1 = 1
(2,1)        1/4 - 1 = -0.75
```

Another solution:

```
[p] / np.array([p]).T - 1

array([[ 0.  ,  3.  ,  1.  ],
       [-0.75,  0.  , -0.5 ],
       [-0.5 ,  1.  ,  0.  ]])
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess it can be done in this way

```
import numpy

prices = [200., 300., 100., 500., 600.]
x = numpy.array(prices).reshape(1, len(prices))
matrix = (1/x.T) * x - 1
```

Let me explain in details. This matrix is a matrix product of column vector of element-wise reciprocal price values and a row vector of original price values. Then matrix of ones of the same size needs to be subtracted from the result.
First of all we create row-vector from prices list

```
x = numpy.array(prices).reshape(1, len(prices))
```

Reshaping is required here. Otherwise your vector will have shape `(len(prices),)`, not required `(1, len(prices))`.
Then we compute a column vector of element-wise reciprocal price values:

```
(1/x.T)
```

Finally, we compute the resulting matrix

```
matrix = (1/x.T) * x - 1
```

Here ending `- 1` will be broadcasted to a matrix of the same shape with `(1/x.T) * x`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two idiomatic ways of doing an outer product-type operation. Either use the `.outer` method of universal functions, here `np.divide`:

```
In [2]: p = np.array([10, 20, 30, 40])

In [3]: np.divide.outer(p, p)
Out[3]: 
array([[ 1.        ,  0.5       ,  0.33333333,  0.25      ],
       [ 2.        ,  1.        ,  0.66666667,  0.5       ],
       [ 3.        ,  1.5       ,  1.        ,  0.75      ],
       [ 4.        ,  2.        ,  1.33333333,  1.        ]])
```

Alternatively, use broadcasting:

```
In [4]: p[:, None] / p[None, :]
Out[4]: 
array([[ 1.        ,  0.5       ,  0.33333333,  0.25      ],
       [ 2.        ,  1.        ,  0.66666667,  0.5       ],
       [ 3.        ,  1.5       ,  1.        ,  0.75      ],
       [ 4.        ,  2.        ,  1.33333333,  1.        ]])
```

This `p[None, :]` itself can be spelled as a reshape, `p.reshape((1, len(p)))`, but readability.

Both are equivalent to a double for-loop:

```
In [6]: o = np.empty((len(p), len(p)))

In [7]: for i in range(len(p)):
   ...:     for j in range(len(p)):
   ...:         o[i, j] = p[i] / p[j]
   ...:         

In [8]: o
Out[8]: 
array([[ 1.        ,  0.5       ,  0.33333333,  0.25      ],
       [ 2.        ,  1.        ,  0.66666667,  0.5       ],
       [ 3.        ,  1.5       ,  1.        ,  0.75      ],
       [ 4.        ,  2.        ,  1.33333333,  1.        ]])
```