# Elementwise concatenation in numpy

Tags: numpy, concatenation, vectorization

I'm trying to concatenate 2 arrays element wise. I have the concatenation working to produce the correct shape but it has not been applied element wise.

So i have this array

```
[0, 1]
[2, 3]
[4, 5]
```

I want to append each element in the array with each element. the target result would be

```
[0, 1, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 4, 5]
[2, 3, 0, 1]
[2, 3, 2, 3]
[2, 3, 4, 5]
[4, 5, 0, 1]
[4, 5, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 4, 5]
```

i think i may need to change an axis but then i can't get the broadcasting to work.

any help would be greatly appreciated. lots to learn in numpy !

```
a = np.arange(6).reshape(3, 2))
b = np.concatenate((a, a), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be stacking replicated versions created with `np.repeat` and `np.tile` -

```
In [52]: n = len(a)

In [53]: np.hstack((np.repeat(a,n,axis=0),np.tile(a,(n,1))))
Out[53]: 
array([[0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 4, 5],
       [2, 3, 0, 1],
       [2, 3, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4, 5],
       [4, 5, 0, 1],
       [4, 5, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 4, 5]])
```

Another would be with `broadcasted-assignment`, since you mentioned `broadcasting` -

```
def create_mesh(a):
    m,n = a.shape
    out = np.empty((m,m,2*n),dtype=a.dtype)
    out[...,:n] = a[:,None]
    out[...,n:] = a
    return out.reshape(-1,2*n)
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to build on senderle's [`cartesian_product`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11146645/4909087) to extend this to 2D arrays. Here's how I usually do this:

```
# Your input array.
arr    
# array([[0, 1],
#        [2, 3],
#        [4, 5]])
```

```
idxs = cartesian_product(*[np.arange(len(arr))] * 2)
arr[idxs].reshape(idxs.shape[0], -1)    
# array([[0, 1, 0, 1],
#        [0, 1, 2, 3],
#        [0, 1, 4, 5],
#        [2, 3, 0, 1],
#        [2, 3, 2, 3],
#        [2, 3, 4, 5],
#        [4, 5, 0, 1],
#        [4, 5, 2, 3],
#        [4, 5, 4, 5]])
```