# make all arrays from list of arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, sorting

I have a list of arrays

```
any_array = [[0,1],[1,2,3],[2,6]]
```

I need to get all arrays where first number is any number from `[0,1]`, second number is from `[1,2,3]` and third number is from `[2,6]`
for example
`[0,1,2]`,`[1,3,6]` etc
How should I solve this problem in python?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cartesian product of x and y array points into single array of 2D points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144513/cartesian-product-of-x-and-y-array-points-into-single-array-of-2d-points)

Comment: Use 3 for loops, checking if the number is in the range.

Answer (score 0):

This is called a *cartesian product*. `itertools` already contains a function

```py
from itertools import product

result = []

for p in product(*x):
    result.append(list(p))
```

Comment: Tested this works perfect. https://repl.it/repls/WhirlwindDarkredAutomaticvectorization