# How can I save all my produced permutations into a Numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, python-itertools

I'd like to generate and save all the produced permutations I get with itertools.product() into an array. At the moment, I'm trying to get all permutations of length 2 of the characters 'ACGT'. When I try to use numpy.asarray(), only the final permutation (['T', 'T']) is saved, which I assume is because the entry is overridden each time in the array. I've tried the following,

```
import itertools as it
import numpy as np

for x in it.product('ACGT', repeat=2):
    array = np.asarray(x)

print(array)
['T', 'T']
```

I later want to do this for larger "word" lengths, but it's easier to test things out when I only expect 16 outcomes. If I was using R, I'd create an empty vector and sequentially add to the vector... However, I'm still trying to get the hang of Python... Please advise!

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/11144513/7207392

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this does not work is because for *each* result of `it.product(..)` you make an array for *that* result. Not for the entire result.

You can create such matrix with:

```
np.array(list(it.product('ACGT', repeat=2)))
```

Or with `meshgrid`:

```
dna = np.array(list('ACGT'))
np.transpose(np.meshgrid(dna, dna)).reshape(-1,2)
```

Both produce an array that looks like:

```
array([['A', 'A'],
       ['A', 'C'],
       ['A', 'G'],
       ['A', 'T'],
       ['C', 'A'],
       ['C', 'C'],
       ['C', 'G'],
       ['C', 'T'],
       ['G', 'A'],
       ['G', 'C'],
       ['G', 'G'],
       ['G', 'T'],
       ['T', 'A'],
       ['T', 'C'],
       ['T', 'G'],
       ['T', 'T']], dtype='<U1')
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! And thank you for showing two examples. I'll remember both in the future :)