# Mapping row values to other values in the same numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

If I have a numpy array with objects such as the following:

```
array(['Ana', 'Charlie', 'Andrew'], dtype=object)
```

And I want to map each object to all objects in the array so I obtain the following output:

```
array(['Ana', 'Ana'],['Ana','Charlie'],['Ana', 'Andrew'], 
['Charlie','ana'], ['Charlie','Charlie'],['Charlie','Andrew'], ['Andrew','ana'],['Andrew', 'Charlie'], ['Andrew','Andrew'], dtype=object).
```

how can I use numpy to map each object to all objects in the same array?

Thanks so much.

Comment: What have you tried so far, did you get some error?

Comment: Why are you using numpy for this¿?

Comment: You can use list comprehension for this task. I would suggest to have a look, or post what you have tried so far, so we can help you better.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cartesian product of x and y array points into single array of 2D points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144513/cartesian-product-of-x-and-y-array-points-into-single-array-of-2d-points)
Search this post for the optimized answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are searching for the cartesian product of the two arrays.

`numpy.transpose()` should do the trick:

```
x = array(['Ana', 'Charlie', 'Andrew'], dtype=object)
numpy.transpose([numpy.tile(x, len(x)), numpy.repeat(x, len(x))])
```

Answer (score 1):

Python lists are generally more suited when dealing with strings. Looks like you want the cartesian product:

```
from itertools import product
l = ['Ana', 'Charlie', 'Andrew']

list(map(list, product(l,l)))

[['Ana', 'Ana'],
 ['Ana', 'Charlie'],
 ['Ana', 'Andrew'],
 ['Charlie', 'Ana'],
 ['Charlie', 'Charlie'],
 ['Charlie', 'Andrew'],
 ['Andrew', 'Ana'],
 ['Andrew', 'Charlie'],
 ['Andrew', 'Andrew']]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code taking advantage of list comprehension should work fine.

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array(['Ana', 'Charlie', 'Andrew'], dtype=object)
b=np.array([[i,j] for i in a for j in a], dtype=object)
```