# Combine two arrays with different dimensions in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop

I'm hoping to combine two arrays...

```
a = np.array(["A", "B", "C"])
b = np.array(["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"])
```

into an array (matrix) similar to this:

```
[["A", "B", "C", "1"]
 ["A", "B", "C", "2"]
 ["A", "B", "C", "3"]
 ["A", "B", "C", "4"]
 ["A", "B", "C", "5"]]
```

I've tried a for-loop, but it doesn't seem to work. I'm new to Python, any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144513/cartesian-product-of-x-and-y-array-points-into-single-array-of-2d-points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
>>> np.hstack((np.tile(a, (len(b), 1)), b[:, None]))
array([['A', 'B', 'C', '1'],
       ['A', 'B', 'C', '2'],
       ['A', 'B', 'C', '3'],
       ['A', 'B', 'C', '4'],
       ['A', 'B', 'C', '5']], dtype='<U1')
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array(["A", "B", "C"])
b = np.array(["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"])

c=np.hstack([np.broadcast_to(a, shape=(len(b), len(a))), b.reshape(-1,1)])
```

Output:

```py
[['A' 'B' 'C' '1']
 ['A' 'B' 'C' '2']
 ['A' 'B' 'C' '3']
 ['A' 'B' 'C' '4']
 ['A' 'B' 'C' '5']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use a Python [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with [`np.append`](https://www.journaldev.com/32780/numpy-append-in-python):

```
>>> [np.append(a,x) for x in b]
[array(['A', 'B', 'C', '1'],
      dtype='<U1'), array(['A', 'B', 'C', '2'],
      dtype='<U1'), array(['A', 'B', 'C', '3'],
      dtype='<U1'), array(['A', 'B', 'C', '4'],
      dtype='<U1'), array(['A', 'B', 'C', '5'],
      dtype='<U1')]
```

Depending on what you need, you could wrap that result in `np.array`:

```
>>> np.array([np.append(a,x) for x in b])
array([['A', 'B', 'C', '1'],
       ['A', 'B', 'C', '2'],
       ['A', 'B', 'C', '3'],
       ['A', 'B', 'C', '4'],
       ['A', 'B', 'C', '5']],
      dtype='<U1')
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it would be:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array(["A", "B", "C"])
b = np.array(["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"])

output=[]

for i in list(b):
    a_list=list(a)
    a_list.append(i)
    output.append(a_list)

output=np.asarray(output)

print(output)
```

Result of this is as desired:

```
[['A' 'B' 'C' '1']
 ['A' 'B' 'C' '2']
 ['A' 'B' 'C' '3']
 ['A' 'B' 'C' '4']
 ['A' 'B' 'C' '5']]
>>>
```