# A Cartesian product function that can yield chunks of result for large arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, out-of-memory

[@Paul Panzer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49445693/5722359) shared an excellent answer on how to perform the cartesian product of a list of NumPy arrays efficiently. I have modified his `cartesian_product_transpose_pp(arrays)` function to show the iteration process occurs from the left to right column of the returned array.

```
import numpy
import itertools
import time

def cartesian_product_transpose_pp(arrays):
    la = len(arrays)
    dtype = numpy.result_type(*arrays)
    arr = numpy.empty((la, *map(len, arrays)), dtype=dtype)
    idx = slice(None), *itertools.repeat(None, la)
    for i, a in enumerate(arrays):
        arr[i, ...] = a[idx[:i]] #my modification   
    return arr.reshape(la, -1).T

mumax = 18
mumin = 1
nsample = 8
mu_list = [ i for i in range(mumin, mumax+1, 1) ]
mu_array = np.array( mu_list, dtype=np.uint8 )
mu_alist = [ mu_array ] * nsample 

start = time.time()
cartesian_product_transpose_pp( mu_alist  )
end = time.time()
print( f'\ncartesian_product_transpose_pp Time: {(end - start)}sec' )
```

However, when this function's argument( i.e. `arrays`) exceeds a certain size, it will require a very large `arr` and fail due to `MemoryError`. Example:

```
arr = np.empty( ( la, *map(len, arrays) ), dtype=dtype )
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 82.1 GiB for an array with shape (8, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18) and data type uint8
```

To address this memory error, I would like to break `arr` into smaller chunks so as to be able to yield smaller chunks of `arr.reshape(la, -1).T` How do I do this when the value of `nsample` increases?

**Updated Test code that I am now using:**

```
import numpy as np
import itertools
import time
import sys

def cartesian_product_transpose_pp( arrays):
    la = len(arrays)
    dtype = np.result_type(*arrays)
    arr = np.empty((la, *map(len, arrays)), dtype=dtype)
    idx = slice(None), *itertools.repeat(None, la)
    for i, a in enumerate(arrays):
        arr[i, ...] = a[idx[:i]] 
    return arr.reshape(la, -1).T

mumax = 18
mumin = 1
nsample = 9 
mu_list = [ i for i in range(mumin, mumax+1, 1) ]
mu_array = np.array( mu_list, dtype=np.uint8 )
mu_alist = [ mu_array ] * nsample

a = mu_alist
start = time.time()
c = 1
result = (
    cartesian_product_transpose_pp( [ *x[:,None], *a[c:] ] )
    for x in cartesian_product_transpose_pp( a[:c] )
    )
with np.printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize):
    for n, i in enumerate( result ):
        #print( n, i ) #for debugging
        a = i
end = time.time()
print( f'\ncartesian_product_transpose_pp Time: {(end - start)}' )
```

**Error Msg:**

```
    arr = np.empty((la, *map(len, arrays)), dtype=dtype)
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 92.4 GiB for an array with shape (9, 1, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18) and data type uint8
```

Comment: Interestingly, you use the keyword in your question. I believe `yield` will help you achieve what you want. Instead of returning the entire array, you'd be returning a generator. If you modify it to return only a chunk at a time, you could effectively have a generator that yields one chunk of your total array per iteration. I'm not super strong with `numpy` arrays to give sample code, so I hope this comment can help get you started!

Comment: @gallen I had thought so too. But, the `MemoryError` occurs at `arr = numpy.empty((la, *map(len, arrays)), dtype=dtype)` before the return or yield. Other than putting that in a `try except` statement to detect the `MemoryError`, what is the appropriate shape of `arr` that I should use?

Comment: So I decided to experiment with this, and if you just remove 1 dimension from `*map(len, arrays)`, which would take it from length 8 to length 7, the memory error will not occur. I don't think that is the "answer", per se. But perhaps a starting point for you explore.

Comment: @gallen I actually think it is - the answer that is. Only I would not completely remove the dimension but split it up into shorter (possibly single element) bits. That way the resulting parts of the product already have the right number of columns and will be easy to splice together.

Comment: @PaulPanzer @gallen I would like the smaller chunks of `return arr.reshape(la, -1).T` to have less number of rows while the number of columns equals `nsample` always. How do I do this while ensuring that the complete cartesian product is correctly passed into the different smaller chunks?

Comment: `(cartesian_product_transpose_pp([*x[:,None],*a[c:]]) for x in cartesian_product_transpose_pp(a[:c]))` here `a` is the array list and `c` is the number of leading dimensions to chop up.

Comment: @PaulPanzer Thanks. It works when on `nsample=8`, `c=1`& `a=mu_alist`. However, when `nsample=>9`, `MemoryError` occurs. E.g. `arr = np.empty((la, *map(len, arrays)), dtype=dtype)`
`MemoryError: Unable to allocate 92.4 GiB for an array with shape (9, 1, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18) and data type uint8`. How do I further chop up the results from a leading dimension that has already been chopped up? Your use of a generator expression is really cool.

Comment: Hm, I do not understand where the `9` in that shape would come form. Anyway, what happens if you set `c=2` or more?

Comment: @PaulPanzer Only `c=1` and `c=nsample` works. All other values fails. E.g. msg is     `arr[i, ...] = a[idx[:i]]
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (18,1,1,1,1,1,1) into shape (1,1,1,18,18,18,18,18,18)`.

Comment: Do you use the original function or your modified version?

Comment: @PaulPanzer I used my modified version. Using `la-i` also gives the same error msg. I have included the new test script that I had used in my question.

Comment: Strange, for me it just works. But only with the original version, the modified one also gives me the shape mismatch error you describe. Could you please try again, and make absolutely sure you use the original? Sometimes one forgets to restart the shell and then ones modifications are not propagated because of import caching etc.

Comment: @PaulPanzer I got the same error from both NumPy ver 1.18.5 and 1.19.0. I confirm that using either `la-i` and `i` gave the same MemoryError. Yes, I did restart the idle-python terminal and had also tested the script on the bash terminal .

Comment: Memory error is a different matter; to address this could you try and go for larger `c`?. For example, if you know that you can do `nsample=10` and now you want to chop up `nsample=14`. then `c` should at least be `4`.

Answer (score 0):

I also had to solve this problem, but this requires numba to be fast. [Here's my answer in a similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63385274/1327143) (originaly limited to a regular cartesian product).