# Using loop for using combinations of three different lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have three different lists

```
a = [139.8, 4.2]
b = [101.6, 114.3, 4.0, 139.8, 4.2]
c = [60.5, 4.0, 89.1, 5.7, 101.6, 4.0]
for i in range....
     for.... #For first combination
            get1 = 139.8
            get2 = 101.6
            get3 = 60.5
```

Expected output combinations:

First combination : 139.8, 101.6, 60.5

Second combination: 139.8, 114.3, 4.0

#Edit
Thrid combination: 139.8, 4.0, 89.1 and so on....

I want to use a loop to get ALL the combinations of three items from each list one after another.
I couldn't develop the logic for this. How can this be done?

Comment: where is the 3rd list? Anyway, what you are most likely after is [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

Comment: Your question is not clear. Better post an example of your desired output.

Comment: what do you mean by " combination" ?

Comment: @Selcuk I gave an example

Comment: @MariosKaramanis I agave an example

Comment: and what about 3rd iteration? what elements do you expect?

Comment: Do you want cartesian product of above arrays ? Share your expected output. May be this solution will work -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144513/cartesian-product-of-x-and-y-array-points-into-single-array-of-2d-points

Comment: @devinxxd what you're looking for is `for x, y, z, in zip(a, b, c):` but this will stop after 2nd iteration.

Comment: @VishalSingh I just edited and simplified it.

Comment: @devinxxd what is the 3rd combination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're looking for [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

```
>>> a = [139.8, 4.2]
>>> b = [101.6, 114.3, 4.0, 139.8, 4.2]
>>> c = [60.5, 4.0, 89.1, 5.7, 101.6, 4.0]
>>> import itertools
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(list(itertools.product(a,b,c)))
[(139.8, 101.6, 60.5),
 (139.8, 101.6, 4.0),
 (139.8, 101.6, 89.1),
 (139.8, 101.6, 5.7),
 (139.8, 101.6, 101.6),
 (139.8, 101.6, 4.0),
 (139.8, 114.3, 60.5),
...
 (4.2, 139.8, 101.6),
 (4.2, 139.8, 4.0),
 (4.2, 4.2, 60.5),
 (4.2, 4.2, 4.0),
 (4.2, 4.2, 89.1),
 (4.2, 4.2, 5.7),
 (4.2, 4.2, 101.6),
 (4.2, 4.2, 4.0)]
```