# Add multiple np.newaxis as needed?

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I would like to pairwise compare (with `<=`) all elements of two NumPy `ndarray`s `A` and `B`, where both arrays can have arbitrary dimensions m and n, such that the result is an array of dimension m + n.

I know how to do it for given dimension of `B`.

1. scalar: `A <= B`
2. one-dimensional: `A[..., np.newaxis] <= B`
3. two-dimensional: `A[..., np.newaxis, np.newaxis] <= B`

Basically, I'm looking for a way to insert as many `np.newaxis` as there are dimensions in the second array.

Is there a syntax like `np.newaxis * B.ndim`, or another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's builtin for that -

```
np.less_equal.outer(A,B)
```

Another way would be with reshaping to accomodate new axes -

```
A.reshape(list(A.shape)+[1]*B.ndim) <= B
```

Comment: Yes, `.outer` seems to be exactly what I'm looking for, thanks! The "another way" probably works, too, but it's much more cumbersome and hard to understand.

Comment: Is there a binary operator that creates a 2-tuple? If so, `.outer` would make a much nicer answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144513/cartesian-product-of-x-and-y-array-points-into-single-array-of-2d-points

Comment: @A.Donda Good idea, but there's none (None/np.newaxis pun not intended).

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer solves OP's problem, but does not address the question in the title in the optimal way. To add multiple np.newaxis, you can do

```
A[(...,) + (np.newaxis,) * B.ndim]
```

which is maybe more readable than the `reshape` solution.