# How to generate vector in Python

Tags: python, numpy

There is a random 1D array m_0

```
np.array([0, 1, 2])
```

I need to generate two 1D arrays:

```
np.array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2])
np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2])
```

Is there faster way to do it than this one:

```
import numpy as np
import time
N = 3
m_0 = np.arange(N)

t = time.time()
m_1 = np.tile(m_0, N)
m_2 = np.repeat(m_0, N)
t = time.time() - t
```

Size of m_0 is 10**3

Comment: `np.repeat` is compiled and pretty fast.  `np.tile` is Python code (which you can read), using `repeat`. Compare that to: `m_`1=np.repeat([m_0], axis=0).ravel()`

Answer (score 0):

You *could* use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to form the Cartesian product of `m_0` with itself, then take the result apart again to get your two arrays.

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import product

N = 3
m_0 = np.arange(N)

m_2, m_1 = map(np.array, zip(*product(m_0, m_0)))

# m_1 is now array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2])
# m_2 is now array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2])
```

However, for large `N` this is probably quite a bit less performant than your solution, as it probably can't use many of NumPy's SIMD optimizations.

For alternatives and comparisons, you'll probably want to look at the answers to [Cartesian product of x and y array points into single array of 2D points](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11144513/674064).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could try `reshape`:

```
>>> np.reshape([m_0]*3, (-1,), order='C')
array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2])

>>> np.reshape([m_0]*3, (-1,), order='F')
array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2])
```

Should be tiny bit faster for larger arrays.

```
>>> m_0 = np.random.randint(0, 10**3, size=(10**3,))
>>> %timeit np.tile([m_0]*10**3, N)
5.85 ms ± 138 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
>>> %timeit np.reshape([m_0]*10**3, (-1,), order='C')
1.94 ms ± 46.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can slightly improve speed if you reuse your first variable to create the second.

```
N=1000
%timeit t = np.arange(N); a = np.tile(t, N); b = np.repeat(t, N)
%timeit t = np.arange(N); a = np.tile(t, N); b = np.reshape(a.reshape((N,N)),-1,'F')
```

> 7.55 ms ± 46.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
>
> 5.54 ms ± 23.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

If you insist on speeding it up further, you can specify the `dtype` of your array.

```
%timeit t = np.arange(N,dtype=np.uint16); a = np.tile(t, N); b = np.repeat(t, N)
%timeit t = np.arange(N,dtype=np.uint16); a = np.tile(t, N); b = np.reshape(a.reshape((N,N)),-1,'F')
```

> 6.03 ms ± 587 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
>
> 3.2 ms ± 37.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

Be sure to keep the [data type limit](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/arrays.scalars.html) in mind.