# Combination of List and Nested List by Index

Tags: python, list, combinations, python-itertools

The output of my script is a list and a nested list. I would like to get the combinations of the two lists by index. In this instance, I have the following two lists:

```
x = [0, 1, 2, 3]

y = [[0, 1, 2, 3],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]]
```

The desired output should look something like this.

```
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (1, 
7), (1, 8), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5), 
(3, 6), (3, 7), (3, 8)]
```

I've looked at many posts about itertools.combinations and itertools.product, but I cannot find anything about looping and combining at the same time, which I think would be the approach to the problem. I want to get all combinations x[0] and y[0], then x[1] and y[1], etc.

Comment: You're looking for `zip`... but seriously, programming is not about looking for solutions online, it's about breaking the problem you need to solve into pieces that can be handled by the computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a list comprehension.

```
x = [0, 1, 2, 3]

y = [[0, 1, 2, 3],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]]

final = [(i,j) for i in x for j in y[i]]
```

Comment: Thank you Mitchell. This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are going to do the catidion multiplication of two array. Here is the reference check and let me know if worked for you.
[Cartesian product of x and y array points into single array of 2D points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144513/cartesian-product-of-x-and-y-array-points-into-single-array-of-2d-points)