# Achieving add operation that maps shapes (a,d) + (b,d) to (a*b,d)

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, addition

I have a numpy array with shape `(a,d)`  and one with shape `(b,d)`. I want to add all possible combinations of the first axis together, i.e. my final array should have shape `(a*b,d)`. This can achieved using the following code:

```py
import numpy as np

a = 2
b = 2
d = 3

matrix1 = np.random.rand(a,d)
matrix2 = np.random.rand(b,d)

result = np.zeros((a*b,d))

for i in range(a):
    result[i*b:i*b+b] = matrix1[i,:] + matrix2
```

But I would like to do it without a for loop, and using numpy functions only. Is there an easy way to do this? Perhaps using `np.einsum` or `np.meshgrid`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cartesian product of x and y array points into single array of 2D points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144513/cartesian-product-of-x-and-y-array-points-into-single-array-of-2d-points)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, use repeat and tile:

```
result = np.repeat(a,b.shape[0],axis=0) + np.tile(b,(a.shape[0],1))
```