# How to create duplicates for every value in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where I need to insert dates for every key. Both come from two seperate dataframes with no columns to merge on. I assume it would maybe be through some for loop but not sure how it would look. Here are the two original dataframes:

```
df_this = pd.DataFrame({'scu_key': [4, 8, 10, 12]})

df_that = pd.DataFrame({'dates': ['02-2018', '03-2018', '04-2018', '05-2018']})

df_all_that = pd.DataFrame({'scu_key':[4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 8, 8, 8, 10, 10, 10, 10, 12, 12, 12, 12], 'dates': ['02-2018', '03-2018', '04-2018', '05-2018','02-2018', '03-2018', '04-2018', '05-2018','02-2018', '03-2018', '04-2018', '05-2018','02-2018', '03-2018', '04-2018', '05-2018']})
```

So as you can see there are repeat values for 'scu_key' because each scu_key will have each of the dates attached to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pd.MultiIndex.from_product`:

```
>>> pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df1['scu_key'], df2['dates']]) \
                 .to_frame().reset_index(drop=True)

    scu_key    dates
0         4  02-2018
1         4  03-2018
2         4  04-2018
3         4  05-2018
4         8  02-2018
5         8  03-2018
6         8  04-2018
7         8  05-2018
8        10  02-2018
9        10  03-2018
10       10  04-2018
11       10  05-2018
12       12  02-2018
13       12  03-2018
14       12  04-2018
15       12  05-2018
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `cross` for pd.merge:

```py
df_this.merge(df_that, how='cross')
    scu_key    dates
0         4  02-2018
1         4  03-2018
2         4  04-2018
3         4  05-2018
4         8  02-2018
5         8  03-2018
6         8  04-2018
7         8  05-2018
8        10  02-2018
9        10  03-2018
10       10  04-2018
11       10  05-2018
12       12  02-2018
13       12  03-2018
14       12  04-2018
15       12  05-2018
```

An alternative is [expand_grid](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.expand_grid.expand_grid) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/), which, depending on the array size, could be faster than `pd.merge(cross)`:

```py
# pip install git+https://github.com/pyjanitor-devs/pyjanitor.git
import janitor
df_this.expand_grid(df_key='A', others={'B':df_that}).droplevel(0,1)
 
    scu_key    dates
0         4  02-2018
1         4  03-2018
2         4  04-2018
3         4  05-2018
4         8  02-2018
5         8  03-2018
6         8  04-2018
7         8  05-2018
8        10  02-2018
9        10  03-2018
10       10  04-2018
11       10  05-2018
12       12  02-2018
13       12  03-2018
14       12  04-2018
15       12  05-2018
```

For even more performance, this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144513/cartesian-product-of-x-and-y-array-points-into-single-array-of-2d-points) has some fast implementations.