# How to do efficient filtering with NumPy while calculating combinations of lists-of-scalars and scalars

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I've been trying to generate all the possible combinations between arrays, let's say `a`, `b`, `c`, `x`, `y`, `z` where the last 3 (`x`, `y`, `z`) can be arrays OR floats. Thanks to useful comments and answers the task is accomplished (BTW, in a more general way, accepting arrays and floats) by

```
from typing import Union, Sequence

import numpy as np
from numbers import Real


def cartesian_product(*arrays: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    """
    See
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144513/cartesian-product-of-x-and-y-array-points-into-single-array-of-2d-points
    """
    la = len(arrays)
    dtype = np.result_type(*arrays)
    arr = np.empty([len(a) for a in arrays] + [la], dtype=dtype)
    for i, a in enumerate(np.ix_(*arrays)):
        arr[..., i] = a
    return arr.reshape(-1, la)


def iter_func(
    *args: Union[Real, Sequence[Real], np.ndarray],
) -> np.ndarray:
    return cartesian_product(*(
        np.atleast_1d(a) for a in args
    ))
```

running `iter_func(5,[2,3],3,[3,6,9],2,[1,2,4])` results in

```
array([[5, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1],
       [5, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2],
       [5, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4],
       [5, 2, 3, 6, 2, 1],
       [5, 2, 3, 6, 2, 2],
       [5, 2, 3, 6, 2, 4],
       [5, 2, 3, 9, 2, 1],
       [5, 2, 3, 9, 2, 2],
       [5, 2, 3, 9, 2, 4],
       [5, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1],
       [5, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2],
       [5, 3, 3, 3, 2, 4],
       [5, 3, 3, 6, 2, 1],
       [5, 3, 3, 6, 2, 2],
       [5, 3, 3, 6, 2, 4],
       [5, 3, 3, 9, 2, 1],
       [5, 3, 3, 9, 2, 2],
       [5, 3, 3, 9, 2, 4]])
```

I'm interested in evaluating each list (appending the results) inside the array and filter if the results are not useful. I know this can be done by

```
#Defining 2 generic operations to provide an example

def Operation(args):
    args=args.tolist()
    a,b,c,*args = args
    return (a+b+c)/sum(args)

def Operation2(args):
    args=args.tolist()
    a,b,c,*args = args
    return (a/b/c)

#Using a list comprehension to calculate, check if the combination satisfies the requirement and append (if)

new_list = [np.append(element,[Operation(element),Operation2(element)]) for element in iter_func(5,[2,3],3,[3,6,9],2,[1,2,4]) if 0.7<Operation(element)<1.2 and 0.55<Operation2(element)<0.85]

#Printing the result
for i in new_list:
    print(i)
```

This results in:

```
[5.     2.     3.     3.     2.     4.     1.1111 0.8333]
[5.     2.     3.     6.     2.     1.     1.1111 0.8333]
[5.     2.     3.     6.     2.     2.     1.     0.8333]
[5.     2.     3.     6.     2.     4.     0.8333 0.8333]
[5.     2.     3.     9.     2.     1.     0.8333 0.8333]
[5.     2.     3.     9.     2.     2.     0.7692 0.8333]
[5.     3.     3.     6.     2.     2.     1.1    0.5556]
[5.     3.     3.     6.     2.     4.     0.9167 0.5556]
[5.     3.     3.     9.     2.     1.     0.9167 0.5556]
[5.     3.     3.     9.     2.     2.     0.8462 0.5556]
[5.     3.     3.     9.     2.     4.     0.7333 0.5556]
```

which works as a filter. The **Question** is: how could I do it directly evaluating the operations and conditions when a combination is generated?

This way I would be appending less elements and not iterating through every set once the combinations are calculated, which, I imagine, is better.

Comment: Are you sure it's `iter_func(5,[2,3],3,3,2,[1,2,4])` and not `iter_func(5,[2,3],3,[3,6,9],2,[1,2,4])`?

Comment: @mathfux correct! it was a typo... it is `iter_func(5,[2,3],3,[3,6,9],2,[1,2,4])` and not `iter_func(5,[2,3],3,3,2,[1,2,4])`. It has been edited. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple types are cumbersome, especially if you store them in the same list. You could simply do:

```
data = ([5],[2,3],[3],[3,6,9],[2],[1,2,4])
plug_in = np.stack(np.meshgrid(*data), axis=-1).reshape(-1, len(data)) #Cartesian product

op1 = np.sum(plug_in[:,:3], axis=1)/np.sum(plug_in[:,3:], axis=1) #results of your operation1
op2 = plug_in[:,0]/plug_in[:,1]/plug_in[:,2] #results of your operation2

plug_in = np.column_stack([plug_in, op1[:,None], op2[:,None]]) #append two extra columns
plug_in = plug_in[(0.7 < op1) & (op1 < 1.2) & (0.55 < op2) & (op2 < 0.85)] #drop rows you don't need
with np.printoptions(precision=4): #print it nice!
    print(plug_in)

[[5.     2.     3.     3.     2.     4.     1.1111 0.8333]
 [5.     2.     3.     6.     2.     1.     1.1111 0.8333]
 [5.     2.     3.     6.     2.     2.     1.     0.8333]
 [5.     2.     3.     6.     2.     4.     0.8333 0.8333]
 [5.     2.     3.     9.     2.     1.     0.8333 0.8333]
 [5.     2.     3.     9.     2.     2.     0.7692 0.8333]
 [5.     3.     3.     6.     2.     2.     1.1    0.5556]
 [5.     3.     3.     6.     2.     4.     0.9167 0.5556]
 [5.     3.     3.     9.     2.     1.     0.9167 0.5556]
 [5.     3.     3.     9.     2.     2.     0.8462 0.5556]
 [5.     3.     3.     9.     2.     4.     0.7333 0.5556]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Following the logic of your answer, do you think more "complicated" operations can be defined simplily using `op3=some_function(plug_in[:,0],plug_in[:,1],...,plug_in[:,N])`?

Comment: @nuwe Yes. Why not?

Comment: I'm not very familiarized with the way of imposing conditions to drop rows so I was wondering if it was compatible but I did a test and it worked nicely. Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

This is a non-numpy approach using the `itertools.product` to generate combinations, and filtering the elements as they are generated.

Changing your functions to work with a tuple (as opposed to array):

```
def Operation(args):
    a,b,c,*args = args
    return (a+b+c)/sum(args)

def Operation2(args):
    a,b,c,*args = args
    return (a/b/c)
```

and adding a helper so I don't have to evaluate the functions several times:

```
def foo(element):
    element=list(element)
    o1 = Operation(element)
    o2 = Operation2(element)
    if 0.7<o1<1.2 and 0.55<o2<0.85:
        element.extend([o1,o2])
        return element
    return None
```

Using `itertools` to generate the combinations.  Since we'll be iterating on the combinations, there's no need to use one of the fancier `numpy` 'cartesian product' methods.  We can stick with lists.  Also, start with single element lists rather than scalars.  Allowing for scalars is an unnecessary complication.

```
In [111]: gen = itertools.product([5],[2,3],[3],[3,6,9],[2],[1,2,4])
In [112]: list(gen)
Out[112]: 
[(5, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1),
 (5, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2),
 (5, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4),
 (5, 2, 3, 6, 2, 1),
 (5, 2, 3, 6, 2, 2),
 (5, 2, 3, 6, 2, 4),
 ....
```

Testing `foo` on a couple of entries:

```
In [113]: foo(Out[112][0])
In [114]: foo(Out[112][2])
Out[114]: [5, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 1.1111111111111112, 0.8333333333333334]
```

Reinitial the gen, and iterate with filtering.  Can't use list comprehension without running `foo` twice per element.  (And I don't have a new enough python version to use the walrus operator):

```
In [115]: gen = itertools.product([5],[2,3],[3],[3,6,9],[2],[1,2,4])
In [116]: res = []
     ...: for element in gen:
     ...:     x = foo(element)
     ...:     if x: res.append(x)
     ...: 
In [117]: res
Out[117]: 
[[5, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 1.1111111111111112, 0.8333333333333334],
 [5, 2, 3, 6, 2, 1, 1.1111111111111112, 0.8333333333333334],
 [5, 2, 3, 6, 2, 2, 1.0, 0.8333333333333334],
 [5, 2, 3, 6, 2, 4, 0.8333333333333334, 0.8333333333333334],
 [5, 2, 3, 9, 2, 1, 0.8333333333333334, 0.8333333333333334],
 [5, 2, 3, 9, 2, 2, 0.7692307692307693, 0.8333333333333334],
 [5, 3, 3, 6, 2, 2, 1.1, 0.5555555555555556],
 [5, 3, 3, 6, 2, 4, 0.9166666666666666, 0.5555555555555556],
 [5, 3, 3, 9, 2, 1, 0.9166666666666666, 0.5555555555555556],
 [5, 3, 3, 9, 2, 2, 0.8461538461538461, 0.5555555555555556],
 [5, 3, 3, 9, 2, 4, 0.7333333333333333, 0.5555555555555556]]
```

If needed that could be converted to array, float or object dtype.