# How to efficiently match a list of timestamps to a list of timestamp ranges in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, performance, indexing

I have 3 Pandas dataframes

```
df_a = pd.DataFrame(data={
  'id': [1, 5, 3, 2],
  'ts': [3, 5, 11, 14],
  'other_cols': ['...'] * 4
})

df_b = pd.DataFrame(data={
  'id': [2, 1, 3],
  'ts': [7, 8, 15],
  'other_cols': ['...'] * 3
})

df_c = pd.DataFrame(data={
  'id': [154, 237, 726, 814, 528, 237, 248, 514],
  'ts': [1, 2, 4, 6, 9, 10, 12, 13],
  'other_cols': ['...'] * 8
})
```

**Here is the problem I need to solve**.

- for every `id` in `df_a` find the corresponding `id` in `df_b` and their timestamps. Lets assume `ts_a` and `ts_b`.
- find all the rows in `df_c` between `min(ts_a, ts_b)` and `max(ts_a, ts_b)` and calculate some custom function on these rows. This function can be a pd function (in 95% of the time) but it can be any python function.

---

Here are examples of rows for each ids (id, ts):

- id 1: `[726, 4], [814, 6]`
- id 2: `[528, 9], [237, 10], [248, 12], [514, 13]`
- id 3: `[248, 12], [514, 13]`
- id 5: can be found only in A, but not in B, so nothing should be done

The output does not really matter, so anything that can map `id` to `f(rows for that id)` would do the job.

For example let's assume that I need to apply a simple `len` function on results, I will get the following results

| id | res |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 2 |

If my function is `max(ts) - min(ts)`, the results are:

| id | res |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 = 6 - 4 |
| 2 | 4 = 13 - 9 |
| 3 | 1 = 13 - 12 |

---

**Here are the assumptions on dataframes**:

- `ids` in each corresponding tables are unique
- each dataframe is sorted by `ts`
- there might exist `id` in `df_a` which does not exist in `df_b` and wise versa (but the percentage of missed ids is less than 1%)
- tables A/B can be on the size of tens of millions, table C is on the size of hundreds of millions
- although theoretically there can be any number of rows between timestamps, empirical observations found that median number is in two digit number and the maximum is slightly more than a thousand

---

**My working solutions**

Attempt 1

- create a dictionary `id -> ts` from `df_b`. Linear in terms of length of df_b
- create a sorted list of `ts, other_cols` from `df_c`. Linear in terms of df_c as it is already sorted by ts
- iterate over df_a, then for each id find the ts in dictionary. Then 2 times do binary search in sorted list to find the edges of the data which should be analyzed. Then apply the function

Attempt 2

- combine all the dataframe in one and order by ts `df = pd.concat([df_a, df_b, df_c]).sort_values(by='ts').reset_index(drop=True)`
- iterate over this dataframe in a sliding window approach and maintain dictionary `seen_ids` (`id -> index`) where you put ids from table A/B. If you see the id, in this dictionary, then `df.iloc[index_1:index_2]`, filter them to only rows in C and apply the function

Both attempts work correctly and run in loglinear time but for my data it takes ~20-30 mins to run, which is bearable but not ideal. On top of this there is an issue with additional memory requirement to store additional data.

**My question to Pandas gurus**

Can this be achieved with pure Pandas and be more efficient than my custom implementation?

Comment: *tables A/B can be on the size of tens of millions, table C is on the size of hundreds of millions*, pandas isn't really designed to take on this size of data. This more so when you insist on *custom function*, which requires you to use `apply` or the like; essentially using Python's `for` loop on large data. That being said, you can accelerate your solution with numba package.

Comment: @QuangHoang thanks for looking into my problem. I updated the question with the expected output and clarified regarding custom function (the medium number for applies is ~20) and if there is a solution which will work only for pandas function and will be fast, it will work for me as well.

Comment: @SalvadorDali what is the order or magnitude for the typical number of matches between A/B?

Comment: @ringo most of the assumptions are written in `Here are the assumptions on dataframes:`. Updated with the percent of matches.

Comment: No idea if this would work, but could you leverage PySpark to achieve this?

Comment: I'm guessing you're already onto this - but you say " calculate some custom function on these rows".  Have you tried using cython to speed up that function?  It's likely where a lot of time is spent and if you use cython to e.g. specify types for all variables, you might achieve 5-10x speedup.

Answer (score 6):

Here is my latest attempt. I think it is pretty fast but of course the speed depends entirely on the contents of the tables you try it on. Let me know how it works for you.

Synthetic data generation:

```py
import random
import pandas as pd


a_len = int(1e7)
c_len = int(1e8)

df_a = pd.DataFrame(data={
  'id': random.sample(population=range(a_len), k=int(a_len * .99)),
  'ts': random.choices(population=range(int(a_len * 10)), k=int(a_len * .99)),
  'other_cols': ['...'] * int(a_len * .99)
})
df_a.sort_values(by=["ts"], inplace=True)

df_b = pd.DataFrame(data={
  'id': random.sample(population=range(a_len), k=int(a_len * .99)),
  'ts': random.choices(population=range(int(a_len * 10)), k=int(a_len * .99)),
  'other_cols': ['...'] * int(a_len * .99)
})
df_b.sort_values(by=["ts"], inplace=True)

df_c = pd.DataFrame(data={
  'id': range(c_len),
  'ts': random.choices(population=range(int(a_len * 1e7)), k=c_len),
  'other_cols': ['...'] * c_len
})
df_c.sort_values(by=["ts"], inplace=True)
```

Some stats on an example generation of these tables is:

```py
size_by_id = df_c_labeled.groupby(by=["id"]).size()

size_by_id.max()
>>> 91

size_by_id.median()
>>> 26.0
```

---

The algorithm, utilizing [`pandas.IntervalIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.IntervalIndex.html):

```py
import functools

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


def cartesian_product(*arrays):
    """https://stackoverflow.com/a/11146645/7059681"""
    la = len(arrays)
    dtype = np.result_type(*arrays)
    arr = np.empty([len(a) for a in arrays] + [la], dtype=dtype)
    for i, a in enumerate(np.ix_(*arrays)):
        arr[...,i] = a
    return arr.reshape(-1, la).T


# inner join on id
df_ts = pd.merge(
    left=df_a[["id", "ts"]],
    right=df_b[["id", "ts"]],
    how="inner",
    on="id",
    suffixes=["_a", "_b"]
)

# a = min ts, b = max ts
df_ts["ts_a"], df_ts["ts_b"] = (
    df_ts[["ts_a", "ts_b"]].min(axis=1),
    df_ts[["ts_a", "ts_b"]].max(axis=1),
)

a_min = df_ts["ts_a"].min()
b_max = df_ts["ts_b"].max()

interval_index = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(
    left=df_ts["ts_a"],
    right=df_ts["ts_b"],
    closed="both",
)

# rename to avoid collisions
df_c.rename(columns={"id": "id_c", "ts": "ts_c"}, inplace=True)

ts_c = df_c["ts_c"].to_numpy()

df_c_idxs_list, df_ts_idxs_list = [], []

# the first item in ts_c that is at least equal to a_min
c_lo = 0
while ts_c[c_lo] < a_min:
    c_lo += 1
c_idx = c_lo
c_hi = len(ts_c)

while c_lo < c_hi and ts_c[c_lo] <= b_max:
    # the index of the next greatest ts in ts_c
    # depending on how often you many duplicate values you have in ts_c,
    # it may be faster to binary search instead of incrementing one by one
    # c_idx = bisect.bisect_right(a=ts_c, x=ts_c[c_lo], lo=c_idx, hi=c_hi)
    while c_idx < c_hi and ts_c[c_idx] == ts_c[c_lo]:
        c_idx += 1

    # the indicies of the intervals containing ts_c[c_lo]
    unique_ts_idxs = np.where(interval_index.contains(ts_c[c_lo]))[0]

    # all the indicies equal to ts_c[c_lo]
    unique_c_idxs = df_c.iloc[c_lo: c_idx].index
    
    # all the pairs of these indicies
    c_idxs, ts_idxs = cartesian_product(unique_c_idxs, unique_ts_idxs)

    df_c_idxs_list.append(c_idxs)
    df_ts_idxs_list.append(ts_idxs)

    c_lo = c_idx

df_c_idxs = np.concatenate(df_c_idxs_list)
df_ts_idxs = np.concatenate(df_ts_idxs_list)

df_c_labeled = pd.concat(
    [
        df_ts.loc[df_ts_idxs, :].reset_index(drop=True),
        df_c.loc[df_c_idxs, :].reset_index(drop=True)
    ],
    axis=1
)

print(df_c_labeled)
```

```
   id  ts_a  ts_b  id_c  ts_c other_cols
0   1     3     8   726     4        ...
1   1     3     8   814     6        ...
2   2     7    14   528     9        ...
3   2     7    14   237    10        ...
4   3    11    15   248    12        ...
5   2     7    14   248    12        ...
6   3    11    15   514    13        ...
7   2     7    14   514    13        ...
```

Now we can just do some `groupby` stuff:

```py
id_groupby = df_c_labeled.groupby(by="id")
```

---

```py
id_groupby["ts_c"].size()
```

```
id
1    2
2    4
3    2
Name: ts_c, dtype: int64
```

---

```py
id_groupby["ts_c"].max() - id_groupby["ts_c"].min()
```

```
id
1    2
2    4
3    1
Name: ts_c, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into my problem Ringo. I will test this on real big dataframes tomorrow and give you a better reply, but so far my main concern is `np.where`. It seems to me that this will run in `O(len(df_c))` as it sequentially generates a boolean series and because this operation will run multiple time this will generate slowness. In my opinion there should be a way to use `searchsorted` to leverage log time search as ts is sorted.

Comment: Tried it on a full data and unfortunately as suspected in performs slower (have not finished in an hour)

Comment: @SalvadorDali I have an update coming soon that I'd like for you to try. How did you try this anyway? This shouldn't have worked on large data at all.

Comment: Thanks, can definitely try. Feel free to even create a new answer. Which part do you think will not work on large data? Do you mean that you expected it to fail due to memory (if so, I have ability to spawn jobs on 1TB ram machine, not sure how much ram was used there). Or do you expect it to run extremely long (very likely as I just shut it down after 1h).

Comment: Hmm it would have been both slow and used way much more RAM than 1 TB.

Comment: @SalvadorDali let me know how this version works on your data

Answer (score 4):

### Overview

This problem can be efficiently solved in two parts.

The first part consists in finding the matching rows in `df_a` and `df_b` as well as the range of rows of `df_c` based on `ts`. This can can be done very quickly using a **parallel Numba implementation** (while consuming only a fraction of the input datasets).

The second part consists in computing the user-defined function based that are possibly Pandas ones. This later operation is **inherently slow and memory expensive**. Indeed, Pandas functions operate mainly on dataframes/series which are not efficient here. Iterating over Pandas dataframe containing generic pure-Python type is known to be painfully slow. Building many small dataframe is slow (there is a pretty high overhead to even create an empty dataframe) but memory efficient. Creating a big dataframe is significantly faster but this is clearly not memory efficient since it nearly force many rows to be replicated (dozens or even hundreds of time due to the number of items in `df_c` to extract per id of `df_a`/`df_b`. In the end, the fastest Pandas solution will be far slower than the optimal time (by at least one order of magnitude). Also note that parallelism will barely help here because of the GIL preventing multithreaded code to be fast and pickling preventing multiprocessing to be fast. In addition, tools like Numba or Cython cannot help for user-defined generic pure-Python functions. AFAIK, **the only way to make this part really fast and memory efficient is simply not to apply generic pandas functions on huge dataframes or generic pure-Python functions**.

---

### Part 1: Extracting dataframe rows

The first part can be done using a parallel Numba (JIT compiler) code. While Numba do not supports Pandas directly, Pandas uses mainly Numpy internally which is well supported by Numba. The computation can be split in many chunks computed efficiently in parallel. The main idea is to build a fast index of `df_b` so to merge `df_a` and `df_b` in linear time, and use a binary search so to find ranges of matching rows in `df_c`. The resulting code is *very fast*. The thing is the output format is not very efficient for the part 2. Here is the code:

```py
import numba as nb
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Feel free to change the signature based on the actual type of your dataframe. Smaller types take less memory and tends to be faster because of that.
@nb.njit('(int64[::1], int64[::1], int64[::1], int64[::1], int64[::1])', parallel=True)
def find_matching_rows(df_a_id, df_a_ts, df_b_id, df_b_ts, df_c_ts):
    # Build an index of `df_b` IDs

    b_index = {df_b_id[i]: i for i in range(df_b_id.size)}


    # Mark the `df_a` rows found in `df_b` (parallel)

    found = np.empty(df_a_id.size, np.bool_)
    for a_row in nb.prange(df_a_id.size):
        a_id = df_a_id[a_row]
        found[a_row] = a_id in b_index


    # Count the number of valid rows (parallel)

    count = 0
    for a_row in nb.prange(df_a_id.size):
        count += found[a_row]


    # Count the number of valid item per chunk and
    # the offsets of the output of each chunk (mainly parallel)

    chunk_size = 32768
    chunk_count = (found.size + chunk_size - 1) // chunk_size
    count_by_chunk = np.empty(chunk_count, np.int32)

    for i in nb.prange(chunk_count):
        count_by_chunk[i] = np.sum(found[i*chunk_size:(i+1)*chunk_size])

    out_offsets = np.zeros(chunk_count + 1, np.int32)

    for i in range(chunk_count):
        out_offsets[i+1] = out_offsets[i] + count_by_chunk[i]

    assert out_offsets[chunk_count] == count


    # Main chunk-based computation (parallel)

    a_rows = np.empty(count, np.int32)              # `df_a` indices
    b_rows = np.empty(count, np.int32)              # `df_b` indices
    c_rows = np.empty((count, 2), np.int32)         # Start/end indices

    for chunk_id in nb.prange(chunk_count):
        a_row_start = chunk_id * chunk_size
        a_row_end = min(df_a_id.size, a_row_start + chunk_size)
        offset = out_offsets[chunk_id]
        for a_row in range(a_row_start, a_row_end):
            # Discard ids of `df_a` not in `df_b`
            if not found[a_row]:
                continue
            a_id = df_a_id[a_row]
            b_row = b_index[a_id]
            ts_a, ts_b = df_a_ts[a_row], df_b_ts[b_row]
            ts_min, ts_max = min(ts_a, ts_b), max(ts_a, ts_b)
            c_start_row = np.searchsorted(df_c_ts, ts_min, 'left')  # Included
            c_end_row = np.searchsorted(df_c_ts, ts_max, 'right')   # Excluded
            # If the is no row found in `df_c`
            if c_start_row >= c_end_row:
                c_start_row = c_end_row = -1                        # Not discarded (may be useful)
            # Save results
            a_rows[offset] = a_row
            b_rows[offset] = b_row
            c_rows[offset, 0] = c_start_row
            c_rows[offset, 1] = c_end_row
            offset += 1

    return (a_rows, b_rows, c_rows)
```

Here is the way to call the function:

```py
a_rows, b_rows, c_rows = find_matching_rows(
    df_a['id'].values, df_a['ts'].values,
    df_b['id'].values, df_b['ts'].values,
    df_c['ts'].values
)
```

---

### Part 2: dataframe & user-defined functions

As seen before, generic approaches are inherently inefficient (for both speed and memory-usage). One solution is to tweak your operation to apply them directly in the previous Numba code. This would make the overall implementation both very fast (ie. parallel and JIT-compiled) and memory efficient (ie. computed on the fly -- no need for a huge temporary dataframe). That being said, Numba do not support generic pure-Python object types nor pandas functions so this can require some non-trivial code rework regarding your actual dataframe.

The inefficient alternative is to create a big temporary dataframe from index-based arrays previously created by `find_matching_rows`. Here is an example of Numba code to do that:

```py
@nb.njit('(int32[::1], int32[::1], int32[:,::1])')
def build_df_index(a_rows, b_rows, c_rows):
    n = a_rows.size

    # Count he total number of rows to be computed in df_c
    count = 0
    for i in range(n):
        count += c_rows[i, 1] - c_rows[i, 0]

    new_a_rows = np.empty(count, np.int32)
    new_b_rows = np.empty(count, np.int32)
    new_c_rows = np.empty(count, np.int32)
    offset = 0

    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(c_rows[i, 1] - c_rows[i, 0]):
            new_a_rows[offset] = a_rows[i]
            new_b_rows[offset] = b_rows[i]
            new_c_rows[offset] = c_rows[i,0] + j
            offset += 1

    return (new_a_rows, new_b_rows, new_c_rows)
```

The resulting index arrays can be use to create the final dataframe with `df_a.iloc[new_a_rows]`, `df_b.iloc[new_b_rows]` and `df_c.iloc[new_c_rows]` for example. If your actual dataframe contains only uniform types or ones that Numba supports, then you can directly generate this temporary dataframe with Numba (significantly faster than Pandas `iloc`, especially if performed in parallel).

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @QuangHong. it may not be efficient for taking up this large data.

However, i tried  your sample input using pandas

Merge `df_a` and `df_b` based on `id` column. did `inner` join as we need the rows which are there on both

```
df_merge_a_b = df_a.merge(df_b, on=['id'], how='inner')
```

Find the minimum and maximum of the corresponding rows

```
df_merge_a_b["min_ab"] = df_merge_a_b[["ts_x", "ts_y"]].min(axis=1)
df_merge_a_b["max_ab"] = df_merge_a_b[["ts_x", "ts_y"]].max(axis=1)
```

With the min and max in place, for each row in the dataframe, find the ids which are between min and max

```
def get_matching_rows(row):
    min_ab = row["min_ab"]
    max_ab = row["max_ab"]
    result = df_c[df_c["ts"].between(min_ab, max_ab)] 
    print(result)
    ## apply custom function on result and return
    
    
df_merge_a_b.apply(lambda x: get_matching_rows(x), axis=1)
```

Sample output

```
    id  ts other_cols
2  726   4        ...
3  814   6        ...
    id  ts other_cols
6  248  12        ...
7  514  13        ...
    id  ts other_cols
4  528   9        ...
5  237  10        ...
6  248  12        ...
7  514  13        ...
```

apply the custom function and concat all the output together.

May not be super efficient.. but wanted to try the sample in pandas.

Comment: Thanks for looking into my problem Srinath. I will test this on real big dataframes tomorrow and give you a better reply, but so far my main concern is `df_c[df_c["ts"].between(min_ab, max_ab)]`. It seems to me that this will run in `O(len(df_c))` as it sequentially generates a boolean series and because this operation will run multiple time this will generate slowness. In my opinion there should be a way to use `searchsorted` to leverage log time search as ts is sorted.

Comment: Tried it on a full data and unfortunately as suspected in performs slower (have not finished in an hour)

Comment: can you post the size of all three tables ? may be I will mimic the size and try improving the answer. without the data, its tough to improve. hope you understand.

Comment: I wrote detailed information about the data in `assumptions on dataframes:`. Relevant part is `tables A/B can be on the size of tens of millions, table C is on the size of hundreds of millions`.

Answer (score 3):

```py
# Set some indices, note how df_c is different.
df_a = df_a.set_index('id')
df_b = df_b.set_index('id')
# Looks like maybe your `ts` is already sorted? If so, `sort_index()` isn't necessary~
df_c = df_c.set_index('ts').sort_index()

# concat them together, then get the min and max from each ts.
df = pd.concat([df_a, df_b])
# Producing the min/max this way should be fast.
# sort=False is optional for performance and means your output will be jumbled like shown below~
df = df.groupby(level=-1, sort=False)['ts'].agg(['min', 'max'])

# Making this work with `raw=True` should improve performance.
# Being able to use `loc` should help.
out = df.apply(lambda x: df_c.loc[x[0]:x[1], 'id'].to_dict(), axis=1, raw=True)
print(out)
```

Output:

```
id
1                       {4: 726, 6: 814}
5                                     {}
3                     {12: 248, 13: 514}
2    {9: 528, 10: 237, 12: 248, 13: 514}
dtype: object
```

I don't have a ton of faith in this method, but I'd love to know how it turns out~

---

After setting and sorting (where necessary) indices, the one-liner would be:

```
# Only concating `ts` will be faster, no need to drag everything along.
out = (pd.concat([df_a[['ts']], df_b[['ts']]])
         .groupby(level=-1, sort=False)['ts']
         .agg(['min', 'max'])
         .apply(lambda x: df_c.loc[x[0]:x[1], 'id'].to_dict(), axis=1, raw=True)
         # See this alternative if only ts are needed:
         #.apply(lambda x: set(df_c.loc[x[0]:x[1], 'id'].index), axis=1, raw=True)
)
```

Comment: This being said, you should probably be using something like `pyspark` for a dataset this large~

Answer (score 1):

To add one possible optimisation to the existing answers: if there are duplicates in `(min, max)` combinations, then you could perform the lookup/calculation in `df_c` only for the unique `(min, max)` values (or alternatively implement caching).

This could be a substantial reduction in computation if the timestamps are at a fairly low resolution (e.g. days), but probably of not much use if timestamps are at high resolution (e.g. picoseconds). Of course, if you want fast approximate answers, you could always round the timestamps to a tolerable margin of error.

In practice, this would look as follows :

```py
from pandas import DataFrame, merge

df_a = DataFrame(
    data={"id": [1, 5, 3, 2], "ts": [3, 5, 11, 14], "other_cols": ["..."] * 4}
)

df_b = DataFrame(data={"id": [2, 1, 3], "ts": [7, 8, 15], "other_cols": ["..."] * 3})

df_c = DataFrame(
    data={
        "id": [154, 237, 726, 814, 528, 237, 248, 514],
        "ts": [1, 2, 4, 6, 9, 10, 12, 13],
        "other_cols": ["..."] * 8,
    }
)
# indexing and min/max are adapted the answers by @srinath, @ringo and @BeRT2me
df_a = df_a.set_index("id")["ts"]  # keep only info of interest
df_b = df_b.set_index("id")["ts"]  # keep only info of interest
df = merge(df_a, df_b, how="inner", left_index=True, right_index=True)
df["min"] = df[["ts_x", "ts_y"]].min(axis=1)
df["max"] = df[["ts_x", "ts_y"]].max(axis=1)
df = df[["min", "max"]]

# find unique min-max combinations (drop index to avoid confusion)
unique = df.drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)

# proceed to actual calculations (below is just an example)

# make sure df_c is indexed by ts so we can lookup
df_c = df_c.set_index("ts").sort_index()

# if computation is costly this can be done in parallel, but
# AFAIK this would require using another library, e.g. dask
for tmin, tmax in unique.values:
    sub = df_c.loc[tmin:tmax]
    print(tmin, tmax, len(sub))
# 3 8 2
# 11 15 2
# 7 14 4
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that performing look-ups in `df_c` is the rate-limiting step, so I re-indexed to enable direct look-ups vs. searching.  I'm also assuming there is sufficient RAM: see [Scaling to large datasets](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/scale.html?highlight=filter) otherwise.

```
import pandas as pd

df_a = pd.DataFrame(data={             # <-- original data frames
  'id': [1, 5, 3, 2],
  'ts': [3, 5, 11, 14],
  'other_columns': ['...'] * 4})
df_b = pd.DataFrame(data={
  'id': [2, 1, 3],
  'ts': [7, 8, 15],
  'other_columns': ['...'] * 3})
df_c = pd.DataFrame(data={
  'id': [154, 237, 726, 814, 528, 237, 248, 514],
  'ts': [1, 2, 4, 6, 9, 10, 12, 13],
  'other_columns': ['...'] * 8})
```

Combine `df_a` and `df_b` via inner join

```
# combine df_a and df_b to find end-points

xs = pd.merge(
    left = df_a.set_index('id').loc[:, 'ts'],
    right = df_b.set_index('id').loc[:, 'ts'],
    on = 'id', sort = True, validate = 'one_to_one',)
xs['ts_lower'] = xs.min(axis=1)
xs['ts_upper'] = xs.max(axis=1)
endpoints = xs[['ts_lower', 'ts_upper']]

print(endpoints)
    ts_lower  ts_upper
id                    
1          3         8
2          7        14
3         11        15
```

Modify `df_c` such that its `ts` column is an Index.  Then expand the index to include values from `endpoints` -- this lets us index directly into `df_c`, vs. searching:

```
# a) df_c: convert 'ts' to index
df_c = df_c.set_index('ts').sort_index().loc[:, 'id']

# b) df_c: expand the index
idx = (
    df_c.index
    .append(pd.Index(endpoints['ts_lower'].values))
    .append(pd.Index(endpoints['ts_upper'].values))
    .drop_duplicates()
    .sort_values()
)
df_c = df_c.reindex(idx, method = 'ffill')
```

Navigate `df_c` via direct look-up

```
endpoints['val_lower'] = df_c[endpoints['ts_lower']].values
endpoints['val_upper'] = df_c[endpoints['ts_upper']].values

print(endpoints)
    ts_lower  ts_upper  val_lower  val_upper
id                                          
1          3         8        237        814
2          7        14        814        514
3         11        15        237        514
```