# How to multiply one element in an array by another array as many as the number of elements in the second array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

So I have 2 array. Actually my array size is more than this, it's 700 data. but as an example on a small scale as below

```
A = np.array([1.1, 1.2, 2.1, 2.2])
B = np.array([1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
```

I want to do something with mathematical modeling like the following

```
C = [[(1.1*1)+(1.1*3)+(1.1*4)+(1.1*6)+(1.1*7)+(1.1*8)+(1.1*9)+(1.1*10)],
    [(1.2*1)+(1.2*3)+(1.2*4)+(1.2*6)+(1.2*7)+(1.2*8)+(1.2*9)+(1.2*10)],
    [(2.1*1)+(2.1*3)+(2.1*4)+(2.1*6)+(2.1*7)+(2.1*8)+(2.1*9)+(2.1*10)],
    [(2.2*1)+(2.2*3)+(2.2*4)+(2.2*6)+(2.2*7)+(2.2*8)+(2.2*9)+(2.2*10)]]
```

Where this result is displayed in an array with 4 rows and 1 column.

How do I write this logic in python

Please help, thank you

Comment: `(A[:,None] * B).sum(1, keepdims=1)` or `np.einsum('i,j->i', A, B).reshape(-1,1)` (~3x faster for larger arrays)

Answer (score 4):

My solution is inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56261134/17333120).

Try this:

```py
np.sum(A[:, None] * B[None, :], axis=1)
```

`A[:, None] * B[None, :]` generates the product of the terms in the Cartesian product. Then you sum along the correct axis so that the terms you are summing keep the value from `A` fixed and shift along the values in `B`.

Also, the term for `C` you provide is missing the terms that multiply by 8. I can't edit the question, so I'll provide the correct term here:

```py
C = [[(1.1*1)+(1.1*3)+(1.1*4)+(1.1*6)+(1.1*7)+(1.1*8)+(1.1*9)+(1.1*10)],
    [(1.2*1)+(1.2*3)+(1.2*4)+(1.2*6)+(1.2*7)+(1.2*8)+(1.2*9)+(1.2*10)],
    [(2.1*1)+(2.1*3)+(2.1*4)+(2.1*6)+(2.1*7)+(2.1*8)+(2.1*9)+(2.1*10)],
    [(2.2*1)+(2.2*3)+(2.2*4)+(2.2*6)+(2.2*7)+(2.2*8)+(2.2*9)+(2.2*10)]]
```