# Faster numpy-solution instead of itertools.combinations?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, optimization, python-itertools

I'm using `itertools.combinations()` as follows:

```
import itertools
import numpy as np

L = [1,2,3,4,5]
N = 3

output = np.array([a for a in itertools.combinations(L,N)]).T
```

Which yields me the output I need:

```
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3],
       [2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4],
       [3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5]])
```

I'm using this expression repeatedly and excessively in a multiprocessing environment and I need it to be as fast as possible.

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1235363) I understand that `itertools`-based code isn't the fastest solution and using `numpy` could be an improvement, however I'm not good enough at `numpy` optimazation tricks to understand and adapt the iterative code that's written there or to come up with my own optimization.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

`L` comes from a pandas dataframe, so it can as well be seen as a numpy array:

```
L = df.L.values
```

Comment: For 2D you'd have `numpy.triu_indices`, but higher dimensions are more difficult

Comment: What about [`sklearn.utils.extmath.cartesian`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/utils/extmath.py#L557)?

Comment: Never looked into `scikit-learn` so far, I'll read up on it.

Comment: I suppose T is a dynamic list, otherwise you could pre-compute/cache the combinations

Comment: Is T always the same size?

Comment: `T` can be any size though it has some soft upper limit. Its length is great-equal `N` of course. `T` isn't necessarily a list, in fact it comes from a column in a pandas dataframe so it can start off as a numpy array as well. I will edit my post for that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16003217/n-d-version-of-itertools-combinations-in-numpy

Comment: @Curt F.: I tried doing `np.fromiter(list(a for a in itertools.combinations(T,N)),dtype=dt)` but this yields a result I can't transpose simply and according to `timeit` it's exactly as fast as my initial code.

Comment: Khris, can you say anything about what values of N you expect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one that's slightly faster than itertools UPDATE: and one (`nump2`) that's actually quite a bit faster:

```
import numpy as np
import itertools
import timeit

def nump(n, k, i=0):
    if k == 1:
        a = np.arange(i, i+n)
        return tuple([a[None, j:] for j in range(n)])
    template = nump(n-1, k-1, i+1)
    full = np.r_[np.repeat(np.arange(i, i+n-k+1),
                           [t.shape[1] for t in template])[None, :],
                 np.c_[template]]
    return tuple([full[:, j:] for j in np.r_[0, np.add.accumulate(
        [t.shape[1] for t in template[:-1]])]])

def nump2(n, k):
    a = np.ones((k, n-k+1), dtype=int)
    a[0] = np.arange(n-k+1)
    for j in range(1, k):
        reps = (n-k+j) - a[j-1]
        a = np.repeat(a, reps, axis=1)
        ind = np.add.accumulate(reps)
        a[j, ind[:-1]] = 1-reps[1:]
        a[j, 0] = j
        a[j] = np.add.accumulate(a[j])
    return a

def itto(L, N):
    return np.array([a for a in itertools.combinations(L,N)]).T

k = 6
n = 12
N = np.arange(n)

assert np.all(nump2(n,k) == itto(N,k))

print('numpy    ', timeit.timeit('f(a,b)', number=100, globals={'f':nump, 'a':n, 'b':k}))
print('numpy 2  ', timeit.timeit('f(a,b)', number=100, globals={'f':nump2, 'a':n, 'b':k}))
print('itertools', timeit.timeit('f(a,b)', number=100, globals={'f':itto, 'a':N, 'b':k}))
```

Timings:

```
k = 3, n = 50
numpy     0.06967267207801342
numpy 2   0.035096961073577404
itertools 0.7981023890897632

k = 3, n = 10
numpy     0.015058324905112386
numpy 2   0.0017436158377677202
itertools 0.004743851954117417

k = 6, n = 12
numpy     0.03546895203180611
numpy 2   0.00997065706178546
itertools 0.05292179994285107
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort, but what are `n` and `k`? Is it possible to write that solution in a way that it can use a list with arbitrary elements e.g. with strings like these `['a','ret','g','fd']`?

Comment: Also the function used like you do throws an error: `ValueError: need at least one array to concatenate`, it seems to come from the iteration at level 10 or 11.

Comment: @Khris n and k are the sizes of the set and the subset. You can have the numbers replaced by arbitrary objects by creating an object array `oa = np.array(['a', 'ret', 'g', 'fd'], dtype=object)` and then using the output `out` of `nump` like so `oa[out[0]]`. Re the Exception are you running the script as is or do you use other parameters? If the latter, could you post them?

Comment: The exception was my own mistake, nvm that. Thanks for the hint with the indexing, it works, testing the timeit now.

Comment: I can see your solution being sometimes faster but often slower than mine. The problem is that your solution produces additional data that I'm not using.

Comment: @Khris added a new version `nump2` which is much faster. It returns an array that can be directly compared to the output of your function (with L=[0,1,2,...,n-1].

Comment: @PaulPanzer I do not understand why nump2 only returns k combinations? Shouldn't it return all combinations found of size k? e.g. if k = 6, and n = 12, it should return 924

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is old, but I have been working on it recently, and it still might help. From my (pretty extensive) testing, I have found that first generating combinations of each index, and then using these indexes to slice the array, is much faster than directly making combinations from the array. I'm sure that using @Paul Panzer's nump2 function to generate these indices could be even faster.

Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
from math import factorial
import itertools as iters
from timeit import timeit
from perfplot import show

def combinations_iter(array:np.ndarray, r:int = 3) -> np.ndarray:
    return np.array([*iters.combinations(array, r = r)], dtype = array.dtype)

def combinations_iter_idx(array:np.ndarray, r:int = 3) -> np.ndarray:
    n_items = array.shape[0]
    num_combinations = factorial(n_items)//(factorial(n_items-r)*factorial(r))
    combination_idx = np.fromiter(
        iters.chain.from_iterable(iters.combinations(np.arange(n_items, dtype = np.int64), r = r)),
        dtype = np.int64,
        count = num_combinations*r,
    ).reshape(-1,r)
    return array[combination_idx]

show(
    setup = lambda n: np.random.uniform(0,100,(n,3)),
    kernels = [combinations_iter, combinations_iter_idx],
    labels = ['pure itertools', 'itertools for index'],
    n_range = np.geomspace(5,300,10, dtype = np.int64),
    xlabel = "n",
    logx = True,
    logy = False,
    equality_check = np.allclose,
    show_progress = True,
    max_time = None,
    time_unit = "ms",
)
```

[image: Timing of combinations using index, and combinations directly from the array]

It is clear that the indexing method is much faster.

Answer (score 2):

This is is most certainly *not* faster than `itertools.combinations` but it *is* vectorized numpy:

```
def nd_triu_indices(T,N):
    o=np.array(np.meshgrid(*(np.arange(len(T)),)*N))
    return np.array(T)[o[...,np.all(o[1:]>o[:-1],axis=0)]]

 %timeit np.array(list(itertools.combinations(T,N))).T
The slowest run took 4.40 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 8.6 µs per loop

%timeit nd_triu_indices(T,N)
The slowest run took 4.64 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 3: 52.4 µs per loop
```

Not sure if this is vectorizable another way, or if one of the optimization wizards around here can make this method faster.

EDIT: Came up with another way, but still not faster than `combinations`:

```
%timeit np.array(T)[np.array(np.where(np.fromfunction(lambda *i: np.all(np.array(i)[1:]>np.array(i)[:-1], axis=0),(len(T),)*N,dtype=int)))]
The slowest run took 7.78 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 3: 34.3 µs per loop
```

Comment: Why `eval`? It's completely unnecessary. You can just build and unpack a tuple of `N` arguments.

Comment: I couldn't get that working.  for some reason `np.meshgrid((range(5),)*3)` gives `np.arange([0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4])`

Comment: You didn't unpack the tuple.

Comment: OK, feel free to edit it then.  I'm an engineer not a developer, and I have no idea what that means :)

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, however the timeit of my initial code is around `29 ns per loop`, so these are really much slower.

Comment: Yeah, it's really an iterative process, which doesn't vectorize well.

Comment: Addendum, my code does not execute in 29 ns, that was a mistake in using `timeit`.