# How to create index combinations (k out of n) as sparse bitmasks for numpy

Tags: numpy, scipy, combinations, sparse-matrix, bitmask

For numpy how can I efficiently create

1. an array/matrix representing a list of all combinations (k out of n) as lists of k indices. The shape would be (binomial(n, k), k).
2. a sparse array/matrix representing this combinations as bitmasks of length n. (So expanding aboves indices to bitmask.) The shape would be (binomial(n, k), n).

I need to do this with large n (and maybe small k). So the algorithm should be

1. time efficient (e.g. maybe allocate complete result space *at once* before filling it?)
2. space efficient (e.g. *sparse* bitmasks)

Many Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried something? `binomial(n, k)` is a factorial, so no matter how fast you try to do this it will take a lot of time and space if the numbers are somewhat big...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the blowup is not that bad (as mentioned in the comment above), you might try this. It's pretty vectorized and should be fast (for cases which could be handled).

**Edit:** i somewhat assumed you are interested in an output based on scipy.sparse. Maybe you are not.

#### Code

```
import itertools
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sp

def combs(a, r):
    """
    Return successive r-length combinations of elements in the array a.
    Should produce the same output as array(list(combinations(a, r))), but
    faster.
    """
    a = np.asarray(a)
    dt = np.dtype([('', a.dtype)]*r)
    b = np.fromiter(itertools.combinations(a, r), dt)
    b_ = b.view(a.dtype).reshape(-1, r)
    return b_

def sparse_combs(k, n):
    combs_ = combs(np.arange(n), k)
    n_bin = combs_.shape[0]

    spmat = sp.coo_matrix(( np.ones(n_bin*k),
                            (np.repeat(np.arange(n_bin), k),
                             combs_.ravel()) ),
                            shape=(n_bin, n))
    return spmat


print('dense')
print(combs(range(4), 3))
print('sparse (dense for print)')
print(sparse_combs(3, 4).todense())
```

#### Output

```
dense
[[0 1 2]
 [0 1 3]
 [0 2 3]
 [1 2 3]]
sparse (dense for print)
[[ 1.  1.  1.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  1.  1.]
 [ 0.  1.  1.  1.]]
```

The helper-function `combs` i took (probably) from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16003217/n-d-version-of-itertools-combinations-in-numpy) (sometime in the past).

#### Small (unscientific) timing:

```
from time import perf_counter as pc
start = pc()
spmat = sparse_combs(5, 50)
time_used = pc() - start
print('secs: ', time_used)
print('nnzs: ', spmat.nnz)

#secs:  0.5770790778094155
#nnzs:  10593800

(3, 500)
#secs:  3.4843752405405497
#nnzs:  62125500
```

Comment: Thanks. Using `np.full(n_bin*k, True)` instead of `np.ones(n_bin*k)` gives a boolean result and is slightly faster. Apart from this I haven't found anything faster so far.

Comment: @saluto I think i would prefer ```np.ones(n_bin*k, dtype=bool)``` to the ```np.full()``` approach (feels more natural to me).

Comment: Yes, maybe it's more natural, but `np.full` is faster.

Comment: Interesting. Well, trust your measurements!

Comment: And for `k = 2` and `n >= 12` replacing `combs(...)` with `np.asarray(np.triu_indices(n, 1)).T` gives further performance improvement.