# ensuring the Cartesian product of keys appears in a Pandas table

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe that has two key columns, and I want to ensure that the Cartesian product of those keys exist in the table (because I'll have to make a 2D plot containing all combinations). I'm having trouble coming up with a reasonably brief and idiomatic way to do this.

For example, I start with this table giving combinations of fruits and vegetables, and how they taste together:

```
   combo   fruit      veg
0  tasty   apple   carrot
1  yucky  banana   carrot
2  tasty  banana  lettuce
3  yucky   lemon  lettuce
```

I want to end up with this table in which all possible combinations occur:

```
    fruit      veg    combo
0   apple   carrot    tasty
1   apple  lettuce  UNKNOWN
2  banana   carrot    yucky
3  banana  lettuce    tasty
4   lemon   carrot  UNKNOWN
5   lemon  lettuce    yucky
```

Here's the best way I've found to do it:

```
import pandas as pd

# Initial data
df=pd.DataFrame(dict(fruit=['apple','banana','banana','lemon'],
                     veg=['carrot','carrot','lettuce','lettuce'],
                     combo=['tasty','yucky','tasty','yucky']))

# Solution starts here
veg=df.groupby('veg').size().reset_index()
fruit=df.groupby('fruit').size().reset_index()
fruit[0] = veg[0] = 0    #use this dummy column for the join to work!
cartesian = pd.merge(fruit, veg, how='outer', on=0)
del cartesian[0]
all_combos = pd.merge(cartesian, df, how='left')
all_combos[ pd.isnull(all_combos.combo) ] = 'UNKNOWN'
```

I imagine that there's got to be a simpler and less error-prone way to do this... any advice?

I'd especially appreciate it if someone could show me how to do this both with and without a multi-index containing the `fruit` and `veg` columns, because I am *really* stumped about how to do this with indexes. Based on my SQL experience, I'd think these are exactly the situations that indexes are intended for.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sometime after this answer, I added `cartesian_product` to pandas, and soon after [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#creating-a-multiindex-hierarchical-index-object) was added (following its suggestion in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21316628/make-a-pandas-multiindex-from-a-product-of-iterables)). This enables the following simplification which is more efficient:

```
In [21]: p = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df1.index.levels, names=df1.index.names)

In [22]: df1.reindex(p, fill_value='UNKNOWN')
Out[22]:
                  combo
fruit  veg
apple  carrot     tasty
       lettuce  UNKNOWN
banana carrot     yucky
       lettuce    tasty
lemon  carrot   UNKNOWN
       lettuce    yucky
```

*The older answer follows:*

---

If you use fruit and veg as the index, then you could use [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)* to create the `MultiIndex` to [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by:

```
In [10]: from itertools import product

In [11]: df
Out[11]:
   combo   fruit      veg
0  tasty   apple   carrot
1  yucky  banana   carrot
2  tasty  banana  lettuce
3  yucky   lemon  lettuce
```

The tricky part is to grab the right MultiIndex of all the possible fruit/veg:

```
In [12]: fruit_x_veg = list(product(np.unique(df['fruit']), np.unique(df['veg'])))

In [13]: fruit_x_veg = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(fruit_x_veg,
                                                 names=['fruit', 'veg'])
```

Then you can just reindex by these:

```
In [14]: df1 = df.set_index(['fruit', 'veg'])

In [15]: df1
Out[15]:
                combo
fruit  veg
apple  carrot   tasty
banana carrot   yucky
       lettuce  tasty
lemon  lettuce  yucky

In [16]: df1.reindex(fruit_x_veg, fill_value='UNKNOWN')
Out[16]:
                  combo
fruit  veg
apple  carrot     tasty
       lettuce  UNKNOWN
banana carrot     yucky
       lettuce    tasty
lemon  carrot   UNKNOWN
       lettuce    yucky
```

* If `itertools.product` is not fast enough consider using [this numpy implemention](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1235363/1240268)

*Note: this implementation was extended in the `pandas.tools.util.cartesian_product`, which now supports more dtypes (and is used under the hood in `MultiIndex.from_product`).*

Comment: Thanks, Andy, this works well for me. Looks like there is also a `fill_value` optional argument to reindex which can save a step (e.g. `df1.reindex(fruit_x_veg, fill_value='UNKNOWN')`.

Comment: @Dan Excellent! oooh, how neat :)

Comment: @Dan FYI there is a recent [github issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3835) about adding this functionality natively.

Comment: Note that in current builds of pandas, `cartesian_product` is in `pandas.core.reshape.util` (not `pandas.tools.util`).