# Pandas Handling Missing Values when going from Data Frame to Pivot Table

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

Given the following pandas data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['foo' ] * 3 + ['bar'],
         'B': ['w','x']*2,
         'C': ['y', 'z', 'a','a'],
         'D': rand.randn(4),
          })

print df.to_string()
"""
     A  B  C           D
0  foo  w  y  0.06075020
1  foo  x  z  0.21112476
2  foo  w  a  0.01652757
3  bar  x  a  0.17718772
"""
```

Notice how there is no bar,w combination.  When doing the following:

```
pv0 = pandas.pivot_table(df, rows=['A','B'],cols=['C'], aggfunc=numpy.sum)

pv0.ix['bar','x'] #returns result

pv0.ix['bar','w'] #key error though i would like it to return all Nan's

pv0.index #returns 
[(bar, x), (foo, w), (foo, x)]
```

As long as there is at least one entry in column 'C' as in the case of foo,x (it only has a value for 'z' in the 'C' column) it will return NaN for the other column values of 'C' not present for foo,x (e.g. 'a','y')

What I would like would be to have all multiindex combinations, even those that have no data for all column values.

```
pv0.index #I would like it to return
[(bar, w), (bar, x), (foo, w), (foo, x)]
```

I can wrap the .ix commands in try/except blocks, but is there a way that pandas can fill this in automatically?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [reindex()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) method:

```
>>> df1 = pd.pivot_table(df, rows=['A','B'], cols='C', aggfunc=np.sum)
>>> df1
              D                   
C             a        y         z
A   B                             
bar x  0.161702      NaN       NaN
foo w  0.749007  0.85552       NaN
    x       NaN      NaN  0.458701

>>> index = list(iter.product(df['A'].unique(), df['B'].unique()))
>>> df1.reindex(index)
              D                   
C             a        y         z
foo w  0.749007  0.85552       NaN
    x       NaN      NaN  0.458701
bar w       NaN      NaN       NaN
    x  0.161702      NaN       NaN
```

Comment: Ahh, that is interesting to use index = list(iter.product(df['A'].unique(), df['B'].unique())) and would work.  Let me see what if anything else comes along, and I'll accept your answer.

Comment: I've found that reindex work well for this, you just have to create full index :)

Comment: You can now do this with `pd.MultiIndex.from_product` (as in this answer from Andy Hayden: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16994485/ensuring-the-cartesian-product-of-keys-appears-in-a-pandas-table).