# Make a Pandas MultiIndex from a product of iterables?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a utility function for creating a Pandas MultiIndex when I have two or more iterables and I want an index key for each unique pairing of the values in those iterables. It looks like this

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools

def product_index(values, names=None):
    """Make a MultiIndex from the combinatorial product of the values."""
    iterable = itertools.product(*values)
    idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(iterable), names=names)
    return idx
```

And could be used like:

```
a = range(3)
b = list("ab")
product_index([a, b])
```

To create

```
MultiIndex(levels=[[0, 1, 2], [u'a', u'b']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]])
```

This works perfectly fine, but it seems like a common usecase and I am surprised I had to implement it myself. So, my question is, what have I missed/misunderstood in the Pandas library itself that offers this functionality?

**Edit to add:** This function has been [added to Pandas](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/6055) as `MultiIndex.from_product` for the 0.13.1 release.

Comment: AFAICT, you wrote the convenience function that *should* be in pandas

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a very similar construction (but using `cartesian_product` which for larger arrays is faster than `itertools.product`)

```
In [2]: from pandas.tools.util import cartesian_product

In [3]: MultiIndex.from_arrays(cartesian_product([range(3),list('ab')]))
Out[3]: 
MultiIndex(levels=[[0, 1, 2], [u'a', u'b']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]])
```

could be added as a convience method, maybe `MultiIndex.from_iterables(...)`

pls open an issue (and PR if you'd like)

FYI I very rarely actually construct a multi-index 'manually', almost always easier to actually construct a frame and just `set_index`.

```
In [10]: df = DataFrame(dict(A = np.arange(6), 
                             B = ['foo'] * 3 + ['bar'] * 3, 
                             C = np.ones(6)+np.arange(6)%2)
                       ).set_index(['C','B']).sortlevel()

In [11]: df
Out[11]: 
       A
C B     
1 bar  4
  foo  0
  foo  2
2 bar  3
  bar  5
  foo  1

[6 rows x 1 columns]
```

Comment: Can you show a small example of constructing the DataFrame and then setting the index? In other words, is there a better way than the responses to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12390336/how-to-fill-the-missing-record-of-pandas-dataframe-in-pythonic-way

Comment: Thats a reasonable point, I mostly use it when I'm setting up an empty dataframe that will get filled in pieces as I iterate through the elements of the index.

Comment: @mwaskom I would say that filling up an empty DataFrame (and iterating through the index) isn't idiomatic pandas\*... there *may* be a cleaner way to do it. \*pandastic/pandorable

Comment: That may be true (btw I am +1 on pandorable) but a lot of data that ends up in my DataFrames is generated by functions that don't necessarily speak pandas.

Comment: And also often the *labels* themselves are the inputs to the functions that produce the data.

Comment: Note that in current builds of pandas, `cartesian_product` is in `pandas.core.reshape.util` (not `pandas.tools.util`).

Comment: Could this answer be updated to use `MultiIndex.from_product`?