# Python pandas groupby method not working properly

Tags: python, group-by, pandas, time-series

I have a text file that has data in each line and each line has a time stamp. 
So I read the data to a data frame like this:

```
table = pd.read_table(file, sep='|', skiprows=[1], usecols = columns, parse_dates = dateColumns, date_parser = parsedate, converters=columnsFormat)
```

So far, so good.

And my result is a data frame like the example below:

```
Name Local  Code Date        Value
A1   Here   01   01-01-1990  1.2
A1   Here   01   01-02-1990  0.8
A1   Here   01   01-03-1990  1.6
...
A2   There  02   01-01-1990  1.1
A2   There  02   01-02-1990  0.7
A2   There  02   01-03-1990  1.3
...
An   Where  n    12-31-2013  2.1
```

The date is in time order, however I have several groups and they don't have the same number of elements.

What I want to do is to group the data frame by `Name`, `Local` and `Code`. So I can have these values as the index and the Date and Value as the columns of the groups.

Something like the example below:

```
(Index)            Date        Value
(A1   Here   01)   01-01-1990  1.2
                   01-02-1990  0.8
                   01-03-1990  1.6
...
(A2   There  02)   01-01-1990  1.1
                   01-02-1990  0.7
                   01-03-1990  1.3
...
(An   Where  n)    12-31-2013  2.1
```

But instead of having groups like these, when I execute

```
table = table.groupby(['Name', 'Local', 'Code'])
```

I end up having groups like these below. The first group has all data for day 1, the second group all data for day 2, and so on.

```
Name Local  Code Date        Value
A1   Here   01   01-01-1990  1.2
A2   There  02   01-01-1990  1.1
...
A1   Here   01   01-02-1990  0.8
A2   There  02   01-02-1990  0.7
...
A1   Here   01   01-03-1990  1.6
A2   There  02   01-03-1990  1.3
...
An   Where  n    12-31-2013  2.1
```

**Any ideas on how I may have it grouped the way I explained?**

If I use `table = table.groupby(['Name', 'Local', 'Code', 'Date'])` I have one group like:

```
Name Local  Code Date        Value
A1   Here   01   01-01-1990  1.2
                 01-02-1990  0.8
                 01-03-1990  1.6
...
A2   There  02   01-01-1990  1.1
                 01-02-1990  0.7
                 01-03-1990  1.3
...
An   Where  n    12-31-2013  2.1
```

It's almost what I want, however I would have to split it in several groups by `Name`, `Local` and `Code`. Is it possible?

When reading the table, do `parse_dates` and `converters` change something in the index?

Hopefully I made myself clear now. 
Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17027470/pandas-groupby-and-multiindex

Comment: One data frame to each 'Name Local Code' with two columns: date and value.

Comment: what are you actually trying to do (and why)?

Comment: I have a sequential .txt file with several time series. Each 'Name Local Code' group is a different time series. I want to split in one group to each time series, so I can process them.

Comment: when you say "process" that's the part that we're interested in...

Comment: I will use them with some packages from CRAN - Multivariate Time Series (http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/TimeSeries.html). I don't see how that is relevant to my question.

Comment: Why not just use apply with these functions.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround you could set_index and then groupby the index:

```
In [11]: df1 = df.set_index(['Name', 'Local', 'Code'])

In [12]: g = df1.groupby(df1.index)

In [13]: for i in df1.groupby(df1.index): print i
(('A1', 'Here', 1),
                       Date  Value
Name Local Code                   
A1   Here  1     01-01-1990    1.2
           1     01-02-1990    0.8
           1     01-03-1990    1.6)
```

Comment: Sorry, I thought this solved the problem, but it didn't.

Comment: @Lucas obviously you have to elaborate. Anyway, like I commented usually it's better to use groupby methods e.g apply.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your last question:

If you iterate through

```
groups = df.groupby(['name','local','code'])
```

you should get individual data frames per group, ie:

```
for g, grp in groups:
    print grp
```

Comment: I think the OP has this, but the issue is that these aren't indexed by [name, local, code]  (i.e.it's not respecting as_index at this stage) which is what the OP is asking about.