# Show missing (NA) values in pandas.crosstab()

Tags: python, pandas

I have missing values (in fact `pandas.NA`). The **problem** is that they are not shown when using `pandas.crosstab()`. I can offer a **workaround** and would like to know if this is OK this way or if there is a better way.

This is not a duplicate of *[Missing data in pandas.crosstab](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17003034/4865723)* but maybe related. There are also some maybe related bugreports around. But I am not sure if they discuss the same problem because I found nowhere a `<NA>` value in the examples there. Maybe someone can give estimate if my problem is related to the bugs or not.

The raw data...

```
   YEAR  FOO
0  2001    B
1  2001    B
2  2002    A
3  2000  NaN
```

...resulting in this crosstab with missing `NA:

```
YEAR  2000  2001  2002  All
FOO
A        0     0     1    1
B        0     2     0    2
All      1     2     1    4
```

I would expect

```
YEAR  2000  2001  2002  All
FOO
A        0     0     1    1
B        0     2     0    2
<NA>     1     0     0    1
All      1     2     1    4
```

This is the **MWE** producing the problem.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pandas as pd

data = {'YEAR': [2001, 2001, 2002, 2000],
        'FOO': ['B', 'B', 'A', pd.NA]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.FOO = df.FOO.astype('category')
print(df)
tab = pd.crosstab(df.FOO, df.YEAR, margins=True, dropna=False)
print(tab)
```

My **workaround** is to treat the missing values as normal values and doing some conversions.

```
# Workaround
df.FOO = df.FOO.astype('string')
df.FOO = df.FOO.fillna('')  # you could "use" missing also
df.FOO = df.FOO.astype('category')
print(df)

tab = pd.crosstab(df.FOO, df.YEAR, margins=True, dropna=False)
print(tab)
```

Gives the output:

```
   YEAR FOO
0  2001   B
1  2001   B
2  2002   A
3  2000

YEAR  2000  2001  2002  All
FOO
         1     0     0    1
A        0     0     1    1
B        0     2     0    2
All      1     2     1    4
```

**EDIT**: The questions comes up why I use the column as `category`. The answer is that while do `read_csv()` I treat the column via `dtypes=` as `category` by default. This is important because of performance and memory usage when using CSV files with millions of lines. So inittialy I always have a `category` column.

Comment: looks more like a bug. Probably should mention it on pandas' github issues

Comment: Another workaround could be through `value_counts(dropna=False)` and then adding margins manually but not sure if it's better than your current workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to [`add_categories`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cat.add_categories.html) to `FOO` then [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) with the new added `NaN` representation:

```
df['FOO'] = df['FOO'].cat.add_categories(['<NA>']).fillna('<NA>')
tab = pd.crosstab(df['FOO'], df['YEAR'], margins=True)
```

`tab`:

```
YEAR  2000  2001  2002  All
FOO                        
A        0     0     1    1
B        0     2     0    2
<NA>     1     0     0    1
All      1     2     1    4
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you are converting it into category.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'YEAR': [2001, 2001, 2002, 2000],
        'FOO': ['B', 'B', 'A', pd.NA]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
df["FOO"].fillna("NA",inplace=True)
tab=pd.crosstab(df.FOO,df.YEAR,margins=True)
print(tab)
```

Comment: `fillna` would work even with categorical data. You'd just have to add the category. This is also the same as OP's listed "workaround" no?

Comment: @HenryEcker Not exactly the same as I did because I converted the column to `str` which would cause huge memory usage. How would I add a category `"(missing)"` to that column?

Answer (score 0):

I would simply replace the NAs with strings using `fillna`

```
tab = pd.crosstab(df['FOO'].fillna('NA'), df['YEAR'], margins=True)
```

tab:

```
YEAR  2000  2001  2002  All
FOO                        
A        0     0     1    1
B        0     2     0    2
NA       1     0     0    1
All      1     2     1    4
```