# merge two numpy.array without a loop

Tags: python, numpy

I have a two numpy.arrays, I want to get following result efficiently

1.add the element's of b to a's sub-array

```
    a=numpy.array([(1,2,3),(1,2,3)])
    b=numpy.array([0,0])
->
    c=[(0,1,2,3),(0,1,2,3)]
```

code in a loop

```
a=numpy.array([(1,2,3),(1,2,3)])
b=numpy.array([(0,0)])
c=numpy.zeros(2 , 4)
idx=0
for x in a:
   c[idx]=(a[idx][0],a[idx][1],a[idx][2], b[idx])
   idx = idx+1
```

and
2. Get an 2-D array with dimension(a.dim*b.dim, 2) from two 1-D arrays

```
    a=numpy.array([(1,2)])
    b=numpy.array([(3,4)])
->
    c=[(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4)]
```

code in a loop

```
a=numpy.array([(1,2)])
b=numpy.array([(3,4)])
c=numpy.zeros(a.size*b.size , 2)
idx=0
for x in a:
    for y in b:
        c[idx]=(x,y)
        idx = idx+1
```

Comment: Can you show some context? This is possible, and not that hard, but it may not be a good idea.

Comment: Okay, now it looks like you're asking two different questions. Can you give a precise definition of the result you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to these two method to get new array. And I don't want to make this in a loop . I this use loop to make is not efficient

Comment: The two things you're trying to achieve look like entirely different things. If you think they're the same, it's not at all clear what you want to do.

Comment: Could you write a loop that achieves the effect that you're looking for, so it's clearer what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first problem, you can define `b` differently and use `numpy.hstack`:

```
a = numpy.array([(1,2,3),(1,2,3)])
b = numpy.array([[0],[0]])
numpy.hstack((b,a))
```

Regarding the second problem, I would probably use sza's answer and create the numpy array from that result, if necessary. That technique was suggested in [an old Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1208739/1081569).

Comment: Because I have a big array `a`, and actually `b` has the same element.  Can i don't alloc `b` the same size of `a`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, but you can probably use `numpy.empty_like`, `zeros_like` or `ones_like`. Look into `array.fill` too.

Comment: Yes , That's what i mean. But I don't want to use `ones_like`, This will alloc a big memory. And all the elements of `b` are the same, So it's a little memory-wasting

Comment: I see what you mean now. sza's answer is better for that problem too, then, just use a fixed `y`.

Comment: But he also use the loop. I'm afraid it's not efficient. So I should make trade-off on it right?

Comment: As far as I know yes, because numpy array stacking methods need arrays with the same dimensions along the axis being stacked. Test it and see what are the trade-offs.

Answer (score 2):

For the first one, you can do

```
>>> a=numpy.array([(1,2,3),(1,2,3)])
>>> b=numpy.array([0,0])
>>> [tuple(numpy.insert(x, 0, y)) for (x,y) in zip(a,b)]
[(0, 1, 2, 3), (0, 1, 2, 3)]
```

For the 2nd one, you can get the 2-D array like this

```
>>> a=numpy.array([(1,2)])
>>> b=numpy.array([(3,4)])
>>> import itertools
>>> c = list(itertools.product(a.tolist()[0], b.tolist()[0]))
[(1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4)]
```

Comment: This is list. can I also do this in numpy.array