# How to spawn nested loops in python

Tags: python, loops, nested

I've tried searching for an answer to this question and read a lot about decorators and global variables, but have not found anything that exactly makes sense with the problem at hand: I want to make every permutation of `N`-length using `A`-alphabet, `fxn(A,N)`. I will pass the function 2 arguments: `A` and `N`. It will make dummy result of length `N`. Then, with `N` nested `for` loops it will update each index of the result with every element of `A` starting from the innermost loop. So with `fxn(‘01’,4)` it will produce

```
1111, 1110, 1101, 1100, 1011, 1010, 1001, 1000, 
0111, 0110, 0101, 0100, 0011, 0010, 0001, 0000
```

It is straightforward to do this if you know how many nested loops you will need (`N`; although for more than 4 it starts to get really messy and cumbersome). However, if you want to make all arbitrary-length sequences using A, then you need some way to automate this looping behavior. In particular I will also want this function to act as a generator to prevent having to store all these values in memory, such as with a list. To start it needs to initialize the first loop and keep initializing nested loops with a single value change (the index to update) `N-1` times. It will then yield the value of the innermost loop.

The straightforward way to do `fxn('01',4)` would be:

```
for i in alphabet:
    tempresult[0] = i
    for i in alphabet:
        tempresult[1] = i
        for i in alphabet:
            tempresult[2] = i
            for i in alphabet:
                tempresult[3] = i
                yield tempresult
```

Basically, how can I extend this to an arbitrary length list or string and still get each nest loop to update the appropriate index. I know there is probably a permutation function as part of numpy that will do this, but I haven't been able to come across one. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: You want `itertools.permutations()`, in the standard library - or, more likely, `itertools.product('01', repeat=4)`.

Comment: Actually, I don't think `numpy` has an easy way to do this. You can use a recursive function that combines `tile` and `repeat` at each recursive step, but that doesn't seem very simple or efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't actually want permutations here, but the cartesian product of `alphabet*alphabet*alphabet*alphabet`. Which you can write as:

```
itertools.product(alphabet, repeat=4)
```

Or, if you want to get strings back instead of tuples:

```
map(''.join, itertools.product(alphabet, repeat=4))
```

(In 2.x, if you want this to return a lazy iterator instead of a list, as your original code does, use `itertools.imap` instead of `map`.)

---

If you want to do this with numpy, the best way I could think of is to use a recursive function that tiles and repeats for each factor, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1235363/908494) has a better implementation, which you can copy from there, or apparently pull out of `scikit-learn` as `sklearn.utils.extmath.cartesian`, and then just do this:

```
cartesian([alphabet]*4)
```

Of course that gives you a 2D array of single-digit strings; you still need one more step to flatten it to a 1D array of N-digit strings, and numpy will slow you down there more than it speeds you up in the product calculation, so… unless you actually needed a numpy array anyway, I'd stick with `itertools` here.

Answer (score 0):

You can look to see how the [`itertools.permutations`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) function works.