# All possible points of (latitude,longitude) from latitude/longitude coordinates in separate arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, coordinates, combinations

I have latitude and longitude coordinates in two separate arrays:

```
a = np.array([71,75])
b = np.array([43,42])
```

How can I easily find all possible points made up of these coordinates?

I've been messing around with itertools.combinations:

```
In [43]:

list(itertools.combinations(np.concatenate([a,b]), r=2))

Out[43]:

[(71, 75), (71, 43), (71, 42), (75, 43), (75, 42), (43, 42)]
```

but this doesn't work for me because the points `(71,75)` and `(43,42)` are latitude/latitude and longitude/longitude pairs.

What I would like to have is this:

```
Out[43]:

    [(71, 43), (71, 42), (75, 43), (75, 42)]
```

The a and b arrays will eventually be of a larger size but will be kept the same size as they are latitude/longitude pairs.

Comment: The end of your question is not so clear. Can you provide some examples of what you expect?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using numpy to build an array of all combinations of two arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208118/using-numpy-to-build-an-array-of-all-combinations-of-two-arrays)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you want is `itertools.product()`:

```
from itertools import product

list(product(a, b))
#[(71, 43), (71, 42), (75, 43), (75, 42)]
```

Comment: dont forget to import "from itertools import product"

Answer (score 0):

Just do two for loops that are nested and go over both arrays
`for i=0 to len(a) do
  for j=0 to len(b) do
   out.add(coordinate(a[i],b[j]);`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this answer. What is the coordinate function doing and where does it comes from?

Comment: I believe you don't need any `coordinate` function, only make `a[i],b[j]` a tuple or list and `append` (not `add`) to `out`.

Comment: I just made up a class called "coordinate", what @heltonbiker said is a good idea.