# Python, For loops depending on int

Tags: python

I have some code which prints every possible letter combination for a word length of 3.

```
letters = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t"    ,"u","v","w","x","y","z"]
for x in range(0,26):
    for y in range(0,26):
        for z in range(0,26):
            print(letters[x],letters[y],letters[z])
```

This code works fine but if I wanted to see every 4 letter word, then I would have to add another for loop and the same for 5 letters and so on.

I am wondering how I can have a certain number of for loops depending on user input.

Comment: The [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) module is the right place to look

Comment: range(0, 26, 4) ?

Comment: @C.Dlp Uhm, no?

Comment: You want to generate all possible 4-letter strings, correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dimensionality agnostic (generic) cartesian product](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24648045/dimensionality-agnostic-generic-cartesian-product)

Comment: @agg3l OP wants to generate all possible *n* letter strings, with *n* being a user input.

Comment: @deceze Yay, I've just "misspelled" N with '4'

Comment: @agg3l That's quite a typo. :-P

Comment: If all letters are one character long, you can use a string instead of a list of strings.  `["a", "b", "c"][x]` <=> `""abc"[x]`  And you should also look at the `string` module, `string.lowercase`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You [*itertools.product*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) with a `*repeat=n*` where n is how many loops:

```
from itertools import  product
for p in product(letters,repeat=3):
    print(p)
```