# Combination of elements with numpy.array and scalars

Tags: python, numpy

I have a `tuple` which contains a `numpy.array` of arbitrary length along with scalars. Something like this:

```
(array([ 31.5,  31.6,  31.7,  31.8,  31.9,  32. ,  32.1,  32.2,  32.3,
    32.4,  32.5,  32.6,  32.7,  32.8,  32.9,  33. ,  33.1,  33.2,
    33.3,  33.4,  33.5,  33.6,  33.7,  33.8,  33.9,  34. ,  34.1,
    34.2,  34.3,  34.4,  34.5,  34.6,  34.7,  34.8,  34.9,  35. ,
    35.1,  35.2]), 30.0, 0.0025, 0.0, 0.0027, 0.2791, 1.5, 1.0, 100.0)
```

My result needs to pair each element of the `numpy.array` with all the other elements in the `tuple`. Challenge is that the `numpy.array` appears in an arbitrary location within the tuple such that I cannot index with a guarantee.

The result needs to be an iterable (preferably a `tuple`) of `numpy.array`s, something like this:

```
(array([31.5, 30.0, 0.0025, 0.0, 0.0027, 0.2791, 1.5, 1.0, 100.0]),
array([31.6, 30.0, 0.0025, 0.0, 0.0027, 0.2791, 1.5, 1.0, 100.0]),
array([31.7, 30.0, 0.0025, 0.0, 0.0027, 0.2791, 1.5, 1.0, 100.0]),
array([31.8, 30.0, 0.0025, 0.0, 0.0027, 0.2791, 1.5, 1.0, 100.0]),
...
)
```

I have tried solutions presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144513/numpy-cartesian-product-of-x-and-y-array-points-into-single-array-of-2d-points) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208118/using-numpy-to-build-an-array-of-all-combinations-of-two-arrays) as well as `itertools.product`. The SE solutions assume two independent arrays and `itertools.product` is not the right solution either.

Comment: You can use itertools product this way: `list(itertools.product([1,2,3], [[4, 5]]))` => `[(1, [4, 5]), (2, [4, 5]), (3, [4, 5])]` which is more or less what you want. The important part is making the second list (array/tuple) a one element list (array/tuple)

Comment: If I could identify the location of the np.array, yes, but it is returned in arbitrary locations such that I cannot index it but otherwise, yes that would work.

Comment: to split the tuple in two you can use something like `[x for x in s if type(x) == np.ndarray][0]` and `[x for x in s if type(x) != np.ndarray]`, where `s` is the original tuple.

Comment: What kind of library returns an array at an indetermined location? Anyway, to solve that you could check the type of each element or see whether it has a certain attribute (such as `mean`). This falls under the "LookBeforeYouLeap" category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't know the position of the `array`, you'll just have to find it. I would simply code it as follows:

```
from numpy import array, ndarray

a = (array([ 31.5,  31.6,  31.7,  31.8,  31.9,  32. ,  32.1,  32.2, 32.3,
    32.4,  32.5,  32.6,  32.7,  32.8,  32.9,  33. ,  33.1,  33.2,
    33.3,  33.4,  33.5,  33.6,  33.7,  33.8,  33.9,  34. ,  34.1,
    34.2,  34.3,  34.4,  34.5,  34.6,  34.7,  34.8,  34.9,  35. ,
    35.1,  35.2]), 30.0, 0.0025, 0.0, 0.0027, 0.2791, 1.5, 1.0, 100.0)

for i, aa in enumerate(a):
    if isinstance(aa, ndarray):
        break

t = tuple(s for j, s in enumerate(a) if j != i)

newlist = []
for aa in a[i]:
    newlist.append(array((aa,) + t)))
result = tuple(newlist)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
x = (np.array([ 31.5,  31.6,  31.7,  31.8,  31.9,  32. ,  32.1,  32.2,  32.3,
    32.4,  32.5,  32.6,  32.7,  32.8,  32.9,  33. ,  33.1,  33.2,
    33.3,  33.4,  33.5,  33.6,  33.7,  33.8,  33.9,  34. ,  34.1,
    34.2,  34.3,  34.4,  34.5,  34.6,  34.7,  34.8,  34.9,  35. ,
    35.1,  35.2]), 30.0, 0.0025, 0.0, 0.0027, 0.2791, 1.5, 1.0, 100.0)


components = sorted(x, key=lambda xi: np.isscalar(xi))
prefixes = components[0]
suffix = components[1:]
result = tuple(np.array([xi]+suffix) for xi in x)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is another way to do it if you are certain that your tuple contains only one `np.Array`

```
C = [z for z in A if type(z) is not np.ndarray]
B = np.array([np.append(y,C) for y in [np.nditer(x) for x in A if type(x) is np.ndarray][0]]) 
#B can be a tuple or a list
```