# Combinatoric / cartesian product of Numpy arrays without iterators and/or loop(s)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, python-itertools

The following code

```
import numpy as np
import itertools

a_p1 = np.arange(0, 4, 1)
a_p2 = np.arange(20, 25, 1)

params = itertools.product(a_p1, a_p2)
for (p1, p2) in params:
    print(p1, p2)
```

outputs

```
(0, 20) (0, 21) (0, 22) (0, 23) (0, 24) (1, 20) (1, 21) (1, 22) (1, 23) (1, 24) (2, 20) (2, 21) (2, 22) (2, 23) (2, 24) (3, 20) (3, 21) (3, 22) (3, 23) (3, 24)
```

2 nested for loops can also outputs same results

```
for i, p1 in enumerate(a_p1):
    for j, p2 in enumerate(a_p2):
        print(p1, p2)
```

I'm looking for a solution to directly output a Numpy array with such combination (a Numpy array of tuples).

Is there a way to generate such a Numpy array without iterators and/or for loop(s) ?

I'm aware that such a solution will be more memory consuming than using iterators.

Comment: see related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144513/numpy-cartesian-product-of-x-and-y-array-points-into-single-array-of-2d-points

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Install Scikit-Learn http://scikit-learn.org/

```
from sklearn.utils.extmath import cartesian
print cartesian([a_p1, a_p2])
```

It should output

```
[[ 0 20]
 [ 0 21]
 [ 0 22]
 [ 0 23]
 [ 0 24]
 [ 1 20]
 [ 1 21]
 [ 1 22]
 [ 1 23]
 [ 1 24]
 [ 2 20]
 [ 2 21]
 [ 2 22]
 [ 2 23]
 [ 2 24]
 [ 3 20]
 [ 3 21]
 [ 3 22]
 [ 3 23]
 [ 3 24]]
```

This solution was taken from a similar question:
[Using numpy to build an array of all combinations of two arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208118/using-numpy-to-build-an-array-of-all-combinations-of-two-arrays)