# Numpy-native "nested-for-like" structure

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, vectorization

I would like to generate a 2-by-N array in python for use with `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`.

I have a function of two independent variables stored as 1-D arrays, and the data in a 2-D array.  `curve_fit` requires that the data be flattened, which is easy with `data.ravel()`.

However, this is the hack I'm using to generate the 2xN array of ordinate values:

```
ordinate = np.array([[l,t] for l in length for t in time]).T
```

which works, but is slow.  What's the (vectorized?) faster way?

Comment: pv wrote a [numpy cartesian product implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1235363/190597). With that you could use  `ordinate = cartesian([length, time])`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I got the question correctly, you are looking to form a 2D mesh out of the two independent variables stored as 1D arrays. So, for the same, you can use [`np.meshgrid`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) -

```
time2D,length2D = np.meshgrid(time,length)
ordinate_vectorized = np.row_stack((length2D.ravel(),time2D.ravel()))
```

Sample run -

```
In [149]: time
Out[149]: array([7, 2, 1, 9, 6])

In [150]: length
Out[150]: array([3, 5])

In [151]: ordinate = np.array([[l,t] for l in length for t in time]).T

In [152]: ordinate
Out[152]: 
array([[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
       [7, 2, 1, 9, 6, 7, 2, 1, 9, 6]])

In [153]: time2D,length2D = np.meshgrid(time,length)
     ...: ordinate_vectorized = np.row_stack((length2D.ravel(),time2D.ravel()))
     ...: 

In [154]: ordinate_vectorized
Out[154]: 
array([[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
       [7, 2, 1, 9, 6, 7, 2, 1, 9, 6]])
```

Comment: `np.meshgrid` is the function I was unable to find.  Thanks.